# document.all vs. document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

When should you use `document.all` vs. `document.getElementById`?

Comment: `document.all`? Man, *that's* old school!

Comment: Old school? I checked my scripts and they seems to use both options so that older browsers are catered for. So that's not "old school" at all but more like sound programming, showing that the browser makers citing this as a fault are most ignorant and possibly inexperienced coders employed by Google.

Comment: Fun fact: by unholy convention, `typeof document.all === 'undefined'`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`document.all` is a proprietary Microsoft extension to the W3C standard.

`getElementById()` is standard - use that.

However, consider if using a js library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) would come in handy.  For example, `$("#id")` is the jQuery equivalent for `getElementById()`.  Plus, you can use [more than just CSS3](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) selectors.

Comment: I vote for keeping `document.all`! Looks like all browsers technically support it in 2023 and what's the harm with keeping it in place? It's so clean: `document.all.fooBar` vs. `document.getElementById('fooBar')`

Comment: Looks handy indeed. But then, personally, I rarely search for something as simple as an id. And there is no guarantee that (a) browsers will not get rid of such old compatibility code or (b) that they might have already done it. There is no entry for `document.all` on caniuse.com. On mdn, there is a compatibility table which looks good, but they are typically not often updated, once a feature is implemented in a browser. So it's not really usable for checking if there is *still* support.

Answer (score 39):

`document.all` is **very** old, you [don't have to use it anymore](https://web.archive.org/web/20120529072454/http://simonwillison.net/2003/Aug/11/documentAll).

To quote [Nicholas Zakas](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/12/29/feature-detection-is-not-browser-detection/):

> For instance, when the DOM was young,
>   not all browsers supported
>   getElementById(), and so there was a
>   lot of code that looked like this:

```
if(document.getElementById){  //DOM
    element = document.getElementById(id);
} else if (document.all) {  //IE
    element = document.all[id];
} else if (document.layers){  //Netscape < 6
    element = document.layers[id];
}
```

Comment: Where does the (id) come from? Is that a magic variable? Or do I first retrieve it from somewhere?

Comment: @JWoodchuck It's the `id` you set in the DOM, e.g. `<div id="foo">`, then `id` is `foo`.

Answer (score 15):

Actually, **`document.all`** is only ***minimally*** comparable to **`document.getElementById`**.  You wouldn't use one in place of the other, they don't return the same things.

If you were trying to filter through browser capabilities you could use them as in [Marcel Korpel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2408436) like this:

```
if(document.getElementById){  //DOM
    element = document.getElementById(id);
} else if (document.all) {    //IE
    element = document.all[id];
} else if (document.layers){  //Netscape < 6
    element = document.layers[id];
}
```

But, functionally, **`document.getElementsByTagName('*')`** is more equivalent to **`document.all`**.

For example, if you were actually going to use **`document.all`** to examine all the elements on a page, like this:

```
var j = document.all.length;
for(var i = 0; i < j; i++){
   alert("Page element["+i+"] has tagName:"+document.all(i).tagName);
}
```

you would use **`document.getElementsByTagName('*')`** instead:

```
var k = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var j = k.length; 
for (var i = 0; i < j; i++){
    alert("Page element["+i+"] has tagName:"+k[i].tagName); 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how the document.all(i) notation works.  Shouldn't it be document.all[i]?

Comment: @DSoa - After some research, I'm not entirely sure which is correct, or if somehow, both would work. [This page](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0280__Document/documentall.htm) uses **`[i]`** like **`document.all[4].name`**, and [this page](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0280__Document/Listallelementsbyreferencethedocumentall.htm) uses **`(i)`** like **`document.all(i).tagName`**.

Answer (score 6):

**document.all()** is a non-standard way of accessing DOM elements. It's been deprecated from a few browsers. It gives you access to all sub elements on your document.

**document.getElementById()** is a standard and fully supported. Each element have a unique id on the document.

If you have:

```
<div id="testing"></div>
```

Using

```
document.getElementById("testing");
```

Will have access to that specific div.

Answer (score 6):

`document.querySelectorAll` (and its `document.querySelector()` variant that returns the first found element) is much, much more powerful. You can easily:

- get an entire collection with `document.querySelectorAll("*")`, effectively emulating non-standard `document.all` property;
- use `document.querySelector("#your-id")`, effectively emulating `document.getElementById()` function;
- use `document.querySelectorAll(".your-class")`, effectively emulating `document.getElementsByClassName()` function;
- use `document.querySelectorAll("form")` instead of `document.forms`, and `document.querySelectorAll("a")` instead of `document.links`;
- and perform any much more complex DOM querying (using any available CSS selector) that just cannot be covered with other document builtins.

Unified querying API is the way to go. Even if `document.all` would be in the standard, it's just inconvenient.

Comment: It took me a while to realise that in IE, `document.all['word']` returned a list of all elements having the id `"word"`. Even if there were multiple elements with the same ID on the page! So replacing this with `document.querySelector('#word')` broke the page. What I had to do was, after making the IDs unique by putting a number behind them, use `document.querySelectorAll('[id^="word"]')`. Hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 2):

According to [Microsoft's archived Internet Explorer Dev Center](https://web.archive.org/web/20150107115700/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434(v=vs.85).aspx), `document.all` is deprecated in IE 11 and Edge!

Comment: Interesting. Now that chrome adopted it, I hoped FF would join, but if even MS drops it, its really gone. I prefered document.all for its brevity: document.all.editor is much nicer to write and read than document.getElementById("editor").

Comment: It's still there in IE11. In fact, it's even there in Edge. But get this: To defeat all those `if (document.all)` checks and such, `Boolean(document.all)` evaluates to `false` (and `typeof document.all` is `"undefined"` and `document.all == undefined` is `true`). But it's there, and it works. This is even [in the JavaScript spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-IsHTMLDDA-internal-slot). :-)

Answer (score 2):

Specifically, `document.all` was introduced for IE4 BEFORE `document.getElementById` had been introduced.

So, the presence of `document.all` means that the code is intended **to support IE4**, or is trying to identify the browser as IE4 (though it could have been Opera), or the person who wrote (or copied and pasted) the code wasn't up on the latest.

In the highly unlikely event that you need to support IE4, then, you do need `document.all` (or a library that handles these ancient IE specs).

IE5.x does support `document.getElementById` but does not support `document.getElementsByTagName('*')`, so you may still need to use `document.all`

Answer (score -1):

`document.all` works in Chrome now (not sure when since), but I've been missing it the last 20 years.... Simply a shorter method name than the clunky `document.getElementById`. Not sure if it works in Firefox, those guys never had any desire to be compatible with the existing web, always creating new standards instead of embracing the existing web.