# Call the id in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a span like this:

```
<span id="selectedTests" class="emrFG">  
  <span id="lblSelectedTests" class="emrHDR" style="top:3;left:6;font-size:8pt;">Selections</span>  
  <span class="emrHDR" style="top:3;left:190;font-size:8pt;">Tests</span>  
  <div id="recordSet" style="top:19;height:112;width:444;"></div>
</span>
```

The span shows some rows of data and I want to call those rows individually by using  `document.all` method.
How would I do that?

Comment: <span. id="selectedTests" class="emrFG">
   <span. id="lblSelectedTests" class="emrHDR" style="top:3;left:6;font-size:8pt;">Selections</span>
   
<span class="emrHDR" style="top:3;left:190;font-size:8pt;">Tests</span>
   <div id="recordSet" style="top:19;height:112;width:444;"></div>

Comment: @user: Have a look at [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Your CSS (within `style` attributes) is malformed: you have to use a [unit identifier (e.g., px, em, etc.)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-length) when defining `top`, `left`, `height` and `width`. Your HTML is malformed, too: `<span>` elements can only contain inline elements. `<div>` is a block-level element. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.all` is **very** old, see [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid/2408436#2408436). Use `document.getElementById` instead.

Example:

```
var theElement = document.getElementById("lblSelectedTests");
```

Comment: if I do above var alert(document.getElementById("lblSelectedTests")); 
  
it says in alert [Object]

Comment: @user: Indeed, that's the intended behaviour. You can manipulate your elements this way.