# error with using localtime conversion in javascript time function

Tags: javascript, date

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Live Javascript Server Time
function getthedate(city, offset){
    // create Date object for current location
    d = new Date();

    // convert to msec
    // add local time zone offset 
    // get UTC time in msec
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));


    var hours = nd.getHours()
    var minutes = nd.getMinutes()
    var seconds = nd.getSeconds()
    var dn="AM"
        if (hours>=12)
        dn="PM"
        if (hours>12){
        hours=hours-12
        hours="0"+hours
        }
        if (hours==0)
        hours=12
        if (minutes<=9)
        minutes="0"+minutes
        if (seconds<=9)
        seconds="0"+seconds

    var cdate="<strong><font color='b9b9b9' size='1'> "+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+" "+dn+"</font></strong>"
    if (document.all)
    document.all.clock.innerHTML=cdate
    else if (document.getElementById)
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML=cdate
    else
    document.write(cdate)
    }
if (!document.all&&!document.getElementById)
getthedate()
function live_servertime(){
if (document.all||document.getElementById)
setInterval("getthedate()",1000)
 }
 // get London time
alert(getthedate('London', '+1'));   </script>
```

Hey.  I wanted to display the live time of a server (if I know its timezone/utc offset) by using this hack on a simple browser live time script: [Javascript hack link](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6016329.html)

However, using my above code, all that is displayed is: *NaN:NaN:Nan AM*
Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Maybe start with some debugging effort of your own? Hmmmm? There's Firebug, there's JSFiddle, there's simple alert()s...

Comment: I've tried those resources and I still can't find the problem with this code, that's why I've posted it here and asked for help.

Comment: Oh no, another instance of `if (document.all||document.getElementById)` to test for IE or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get `NaN:NaN:Nan AM` or something like that, it just seems to work for me.

But there are some flaws in your code. First, always declare your variables locally using `var`. Now you're silently overwriting `d`, `utc` and `nd` in the global namespace.

Second, this is most likely not what you want:

```
if (hours>12){
    hours=hours-12
    hours="0"+hours
}
```

You don't want a `0` added before the hour if it's between 10 PM and midnight. Moreover, that `0` isn't added when it's before 10 AM.

You probably want to test this *outside* the `hours>12` condition:

```
if (hours<=9)
    hours="0"+hours;
```

Furthermore, you do

```
if (document.all)
document.all.clock.innerHTML=cdate
```

`document.all` is *very* old, you [don't have to use it anymore!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid) Even IE 6 understands the standard `document.getElementById`.

```
setInterval("getthedate()",1000)
```

Always try to feed `setInterval` and `setTimeout` a function instead of a string. To quote [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval):

> Using this syntax is not recommended for the same reasons as using [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/Eval#Don%27t_use_eval%21)

And last, but not least, use proper indenting and put a semicolon after each statement; to quote [Douglas Crockford](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#semicolon):

> JavaScript uses a C-like syntax which
>   requires the use of semicolons to
>   delimit statements. JavaScript
>   attempts to make semicolons optional
>   with a semicolon insertion mechanism.
>   This is dangerous.
>
> Like C, JavaScript has `++` and `--`
>   and `(` operators which can be
>   prefixes or suffixes. The
>   disambiguation is done by the
>   semicolon.
>
> In JavaScript, a linefeed can be
>   whitespace or it can act as a
>   semicolon. This replaces one ambiguity
>   with another.
>
> JSLint expects that every statement be
>   followed by `;` except for `for`,
>   `function`, `if`, `switch`, `try`, and
>   `while`. JSLint does not expect to see
>   unnecessary semicolons or the empty
>   statement.

It's hard to follow your code the way you wrote it; for instance, I trapped myself thinking that your condition `(hours>12)` was within the AM/PM condition.