# Adding hyperlinks to a slide show using javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I've made a simple slide show using Javascript, but now I want to add links to the images as they slide through, so that a pdf opens in a separate window. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Here's the script I have so far. Thanks! Julia

```
              var dimages=new Array();
    var numImages=3;
    for (i=0; i<numImages; i++)
    {
      dimages[i]=new Image();
      dimages[i].src="images/image"+(i+1)+".jpg";
    }
    var curImage=-1;

    function swapPicture()
    {
      if (document.images)
      {
        var nextImage=curImage+1;
        if (nextImage>=numImages)
          nextImage=0;
        if (dimages[nextImage] && dimages[nextImage].complete)
        {
          var target=0;
          if (document.images.myImage)
            target=document.images.myImage;
          if (document.all && document.getElementById("myImage"))
            target=document.getElementById("myImage");

          // make sure target is valid.  It might not be valid
          //   if the page has not finished loading
          if (target)
          {
            target.src=dimages[nextImage].src;
            curImage=nextImage;
          }

          setTimeout("swapPicture()", 5000);

        }
        else
        {
          setTimeout("swapPicture()", 500);
        }
      }
    }

    setTimeout("swapPicture()", 5000);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't feed a string to `setTimeout`, but a function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout: “Using this syntax is not recommended for the same reasons as using [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!)” Moreover, you probably want to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) instead. And stop using `document.all`, it's [*very* old](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is adding an anchor element to your HTML, like

```
<a id="imagelink"><img id="myImage" …></a>
```

and change its `href` (and perhaps its `title`) when changing the image:

```
// make sure target is valid.  It might not be valid
//   if the page has not finished loading
if (target)
{
  target.src=dimages[nextImage].src;
  targetlink = document.getElementById("imagelink");
  targetlink.href = add-link-here;
  targetlink.title = "title message";
  curImage=nextImage;
}
```

---

Also, you're testing for the presence of `myImage` twice. First here:

```
if (document.all && document.getElementById("myImage"))
```

and then here:

```
target=document.getElementById("myImage");
…
if (target)
```