# Remove dollar sign from dom text - not from js code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace all occurences of '$' (dollar sign) in a web page with another string.
The problem is that there may be some `<script>` tags that may contain the '$' (jQuery code) that I don't want to change.

For example:
`document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\$/g, 'xxx');` seems to work, but also replaces '$' from any `<script>$('...')...</script>` parts.

Is this achievable?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I cannot modify the way the page is generated or change all other js parts - neither use some server-side logic. I can only add some custom js code

Comment: you can put script in footer or head tag as you are getting body's html

Comment: Could you not specifically target the elements you require this replacement in? Or better yet, do the replacement on the server before the HTML is rendered.

Comment: Hi @MohitArora, thanks for the comment. I cannot modify the way the page is generated, I can only put some extra custom javascript.

Comment: Like @RoryMcCrossan is saying, can't you add a class (eg. remove-dollar-sign) to the containers where you want to change the dollar sign?

Comment: Do you have nested script tags below the body, as inside other elements and such strangeness, or just in the `body`? You could target `document.body.children` and filter out all script tags before replacing, but doing a string replace on all elements is generally a horrible idea.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but if you change code in a script block that has already been executed it shouldn't make a difference; so, just make sure the replacement is done in the last block to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function textNodes(main) {
    var arr = [];
    var loop = function(main) {
        do {
            if(main.hasChildNodes() && (["STYLE","SCRIPT"].indexOf(main.nodeName)==-1)){
                loop(main.firstChild);
            } else if(main.nodeType === 3) {
                arr.push(main)
            }

        }
        while (main = main.nextSibling);
    }
    loop(main);
    return arr;
}
textNodes(document.body).forEach(function(a){a.textContent=a.textContent.replace(/\$/g,'€')});
```

Based on this [DOM walking example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8747184/2905130)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the script tags

```
[].slice.call(document.body.children).forEach(function(element) {
    if ( element.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'script' ) {
        element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/\$/g, 'xxx');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/a3w6pLbj/3/)

This is not recursive, which means it only works for script tags directly under the body tag, not script tags that are nested deeper