# Iterate through all html tags, including children in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

Just to clarify what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to make a Chrome extension that can loop through the HTML of the current page and remove html tags containing certain text. But I'm having trouble looping through *every* html tag.

I've done a bunch of searching for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747086/most-efficient-way-to-iterate-over-all-dom-elements) and pretty much every [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747086/most-efficient-way-to-iterate-over-all-dom-elements) says to use:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     //do stuff
 }
```

However, I've noticed that if I rebuild the HTML from the page using the elements in "items," I get something different than the page's actual HTML.

For example, the code below returns false:

```js
var html = "";
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  html += elems[i].outerHTML;
}

alert(document.body.outerHTML == html)
```

I also noticed that the code above wasn't giving ALL the html tags, it grouped them into one tag, for example:

```js
var html = "";
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
alert(elems[0].outerHTML);
```

I tried fixing the above by recurssively looking for an element's children, but I couldn't seem to get that to work.

Ideally, I would like to be able to get every individual tag, rather than ones wrapped in other tags. I'm kind of new to Javascript so any advice/explanations or example code (In pure javascript if possible) as to what I'm doing wrong would be really helpful. I also realize my approach might be completely wrong, so any better ideas are welcome.

Comment: So you basically want to take out certain HTML tags and then rebuild the entire DOM?

Comment: Pretty much, I think there are definitely other approaches, but this is the way I've been trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the famous Douglas Crockford's `WalkTheDOM`:

```
function walkTheDOM(node, func)
{
  func(node);
  node = node.firstChild;
  while (node)
  {
    walkTheDOM(node, func);
    node = node.nextSibling;
  }
}
```

For each node the `func` will be executed. You can filter, transform or whatever by injecting the proper function.

To remove nodes containing a specific text you would do:

```
function removeAll(node)
{
    // protect against "node === undefined"
    if (node && node.nodeType === 3) // TEXT_NODE
    {
        if (node.textContent.indexOf(filter) !== -1) // contains offending text
        {
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
filter = "the offending text";
walkTheDOM(document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0], removeAll);
```

If you want to parametize by offending text you can do that, too, by transforming `removeAll` into a closure that is instantiated.

Comment: What would it mean if the node passed to "func" is undefined?

Comment: It means you are at the end of the children. Probably removing nodes while visiting the DOM tree requires an extra `if()` inside `func` that protects you against this. I've used this many times but never to delete nodes. I'll edit it in shortly.

Answer (score 1):

References to DOM elements in JavaScript are references to memory addresses of the actual nodes, so you can do something like this (see the [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smyyzbto/3)):

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('*')).forEach(function(node) {
    if(node.innerHTML === 'Hello') {
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    }
});
```

Obviously `node.innerHTML === 'Hello'` is just an example, so you'll probably want to figure out how you want to match the text content (perhaps with a RegEx?)