# getElementsByTagName("!") returns all elements in documents in IE and ( I think FF), but doesn't return anything in Chrome. Is there an alternative?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: How to loop through ALL DOM elements on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256339/javascript-how-to-loop-through-all-dom-elements-on-a-page)

```
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("!");
```

returns all elements in document in IE, but doesn't return anything in Chrome.

Is there a cross-browser alternative ?

Update:
The ! option returns all tags in a document in an array.

Comment: What is it supposed to return? Is there a special meaning for the "!" in this function?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Get comments?

Comment: This title is just horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName("*")` will return all tags in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for all your help - this is what I was after. Google not that helpful when special characters are involved..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```