# Get all elements in the body tag using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get all the elements (tags) inside the Body tag of an HTML page in an array using pure javascript. I mean without using any framework (ex. JQuery).

I've found that you can use `document.all` but that will return all the elements inside the whole document including the scripts.

Is there anyway I can get those tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to loop through ALL DOM elements on a page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256339/javascript-how-to-loop-through-all-dom-elements-on-a-page)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If you want all elements inside the body tag, not just first level children, you can simply use `getElementsByTagName()` with a wildcard:

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

Comment: for unknown reason, it gives back a null

Comment: @kkDev - If you call it AFTER the document has loaded (and thus when the DOM exists), it works.  See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kKk3X/ for a working demo.

Comment: I get empty objects for some reason, even when using `window.onload`.

Answer (score 42):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) for that.

If you really want all (including nested tags), use this

```
 var elements = document.querySelectorAll( 'body *' );
```

If you only want the immediate child nodes, use

```
 var elements = document.querySelectorAll( 'body > *' );
```

Comment: `document.body.getElementsByTagName('*')` may be more performant.

Comment: @RobW: …and more cross-browser compatible

Comment: user1689607 posted an answer suggesting **`.children`** (for some reason, he deleted it). I prefer the `.children` property over the methods suggested in this answer, because it's more concise and more obvious (`.children` opposed to QSA / getElementsByTagName("*")`. And, after all, the `children` property exists because it ought to be used when one is looking for child **elements** ([`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.children) excludes text nodes etc (but it includes comment nodes in <=IE8 (bug))). (and Bergi is right, QSA is supported since IE 8).

Comment: It should be noted that `querySelectorAll()` and `getElementsByTagName()` have a *different return type*. `querySelectorAll` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), while `getElementsByTagName` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). More on the differences between the two here: [Difference between HTMLCollection, NodeLists, and arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15763358)