# jQuery inside body tag only?

Tags: jquery, count, children

Is there a way to count children only inside  element using jQueru or just javascript?

I tried several methods like:

```
var count = $(document.body).children().length

or

var count = 0;
$(document.body).children().each(function(){
   count +=1
});
```

And every single one counts elements even outside of  tag even and scripts or styles!

So Is there a way to count elements only inside body tag?

Comment: Any more information we should know? Test is working on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ogr8poj/

Comment: $(document.body).children().length works, wat is not working..?

Comment: <body>
 <div id="1"></div>
    <div id="2"></div> 
    <div id="2"></div> 
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
  var count = $(document.body).children().length;
  alert(count)
    
</script>

In code like this it does not working!

It counts script to!

Comment: I use dreamweaver and when there is a script below or above body it counts it !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ushz3473/

In your example I added div tag outside body cause I can't add a script below body and as you can see it counts outside body!

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of elements only inside the body tag, try

```
var btags = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
var count = btags.length;
```

Comment: Tried and it still counts outside of body tag!

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it still counts outside!

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823264/get-all-elements-in-the-body-tag-using-pure-javascript) looks similar to yours.

Comment: I tried few solutions from there but they gives the same results, it simply won't count only inside of body