# How toGetElementsByID in java when there is no ID

Tags: java, getelementbyid, getelementsbyname

I want to make a auto login bot.
now I only found the GetElementsbyID tutorials, but when i look at the code there is no ID it looks like this:

```
<input size="12" name="username" value="Username" onfocus="clickClear(this, 'Username')" onblur="clickRecall(this, 'Username')" type="text">
```

my question is: How do fill in my text in these textboxes?

Comment: it's `getElementById` not  `GetElementsbyID`

Comment: It’s not Java but JavaScript

Comment: Oke but. how do i put in the text when there is no Id?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823264/get-all-elements-in-the-body-tag-using-pure-javascript and take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

use `querySelector()` to access the element and use `value` to change the value.

```
 var input = document.querySelector('input[name="username"]');
 input.value= 'whatever;
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no Id, you will have to access the element by another property.

In your specific example, you could probably do with `getElementsByName('username')`.

Note that unlike `GetElementById`, this is element*s*, plural. You will receive a list of matches.

If you know that you are always matching exactly one element with this query, you can for instance write

```js
document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value = 'test';
```

```html
<input size="12" name="username" value="Username" onfocus="clickClear(this, 'Username')" onblur="clickRecall(this, 'Username')" type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks this is really helpfull!