# How to get only all HTML tags to list from string using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get list with only all HTML tags from string? We can use javascript, jquery or any C# library or api.
We have one big string:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
qwe
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
<a>xyz</a>
<button type="button"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get list = {`<html>,<head>,<body>,<button type="button">,<button>,<a>,<button>`}
I need to count how many times occurs each HTML tag in string and show 3 the most common.

Comment: I tried to use HtmlAgilityPack and var bla = document.getElementsByTagName("*"); but i dont know what to next

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all elements in the body tag using pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823264/get-all-elements-in-the-body-tag-using-pure-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
var tagList = {};
var tag;
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
  tag = node.tagName.toLowerCase();
  if (!tagList[tag]) {
    tagList[tag] = 1;
  } else {
    tagList[tag]++;
  }
});
tagList; // object, where key - html tag, and value – tag count per html document
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Here it is you want. But you would be able to find [at here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823264/get-all-elements-in-the-body-tag-using-pure-javascript) if you had searched a little.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tags = $("*").map(function() {
   return this.nodeName; 
}).get()
// Filter out the duplicates
.filter(function(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
});
console.log(tags);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
qwe
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
<a>xyz</a>
<button type="button"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm running this code on the server, I can't use JQuery there

Comment: I've a string containing html and I want to get the tags from it