# JS Get list of all available standard HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to get JS to export a list of **all possible standard HTML tags**?

for instance, if we would like to get all available style properties we could

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
for(var property in d.style) console.log(property); // would print out all properties;
```

But we would like to know if there is a way to get all available HTML tags instead.

If such a thing is not possible, does anybody know where can we get our hands on such a list? we couldn't find it in either comma delimited / json... all we found was websites with references etc...

- NOTE - we are not talking about `document.querySelectorAll('*')` which will give us all elements in the DOM. we are looking for **ALL POSSIBLE STANDARD HTML TAGS**

Comment: There is standard and non-standard tags. Think about XML structure (that is similar to HTML), it's infinite amount of possible tags. Maybe you wish to list all tags that are present in your DOM? Then `elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")`

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823264/get-all-elements-in-the-body-tag-using-pure-javascript

Comment: Nope, all possible HTML tags, not all which are inside the DOM

Comment: Go to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ or https://techspirited.com/all-html-tags-list-of-all-html-tags. Copy the tag table contents. Paste to excel. Remove the descriptions. Save as csv.

Comment: Pointy please place the code in your console and let me know what comes up

Comment: @Kaiido — That returns 74 items (including all the false positives). HTML 4 defined over 90 elements. HTML 5 adds more.

Comment: @levi well what do you know. I stand corrected.

Comment: It's harder than it seems. Do you include foreign elements, or only those in the HTML namespace? Do you include obsolete elements, when browsers may well have implementation code specifically to support them? What about `<hgroup>` - standard in the WHATWG Living Standard, but obsolete in W3C HTML5 spec?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no list of "all possible" HTML tags, because an infinite number of HTML tags are *possible*. There's [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#elements-3), which list all current standard HTML tags, but of course, you can create [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) with their own tags.

Out of curiousity, I looked to see how hard it is to get the list from the spec's web page. I came up with this:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("th > code[id*='elements-3:'] > a")].map(a => a.textContent).join()
```

So, not difficult.

If you run that in the console when you have the spec open from the link above, as of this writing in October 2018 *(and also this edit five years later)*, it lists 112 elements:

```
a,abbr,address,area,article,aside,audio,b,base,bdi,bdo,blockquote,body,br,button,canvas,caption,cite,code,col,colgroup,data,datalist,dd,del,details,dfn,dialog,div,dl,dt,em,embed,fieldset,figcaption,figure,footer,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,head,header,hgroup,hr,html,i,iframe,img,input,ins,kbd,label,legend,li,link,main,map,mark,menu,meta,meter,nav,noscript,object,ol,optgroup,option,output,p,param,picture,pre,progress,q,rp,rt,ruby,s,samp,script,section,select,slot,small,source,span,strong,style,sub,summary,sup,table,tbody,td,template,textarea,tfoot,th,thead,time,title,tr,track,u,ul,var,video,wbr
```

---

It's tempting to use a code-based approach, looking for HTML element constructors by examining the properties of `window`:

```js
const show = msg => {
  const p = document.createElement('pre');
  p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(p);
};
const tags = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)
  .map(key => {
    const match = /^HTML(.+)Element$/.exec(key);
    return match && match[1].toLowerCase();
  })
  .filter(tag => tag && tag !== "unknown");
show(`${tags.length} tags found:`);
tags.forEach(show);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

**But**:

- That only tells you what the browser supports, which may not be the full range of defined HTML and will vary from vendor to vendor (for me, Chrome lists 71 tags, whereas Firefox and Edge list 67).
- It isn't a one-to-one list. For instance, `tbody`, `tfoot`, and `thead` all use `HTMLTableSectionElement`, so that means
- The above lists `tablesection`, but that isn't a tag, and
- The above doesn't list `tbody`, `tfoot`, or `thead`
- Not all elements have their own constructors, many of them are just `HTMLElement` instances (`code`, `cite`, `b`, `aside`, ...)

So, yeah, the code approach doesn't work. You'll have to get the list from the spec.

Comment: I have updated the question, I need a simple comma delimited list and can't find it... thanks anyway

Comment: "all of the HTML element constructors" — They don't correspond 1:1 to HTML elements though. When I run that code I get `tablesection` but there is no `<tablesection>`, and I don't get `code` but `<code>` is an element. (There are lots of other examples, I just grabbed the first false positive and false negative that occurred to me)

Comment: @Quentin - Thought you'd find the latest update (with `querySelectorAll`) amusing. :-)

Comment: "a,abbr,address,area,article,aside,audio,b,base,bdi,bdo,blockquote,body,br,button,canvas,caption,cite,code,col,colgroup,data,datalist,dd,del,details,dfn,dialog,div,dl,dt,em,embed,fieldset,figcaption,figure,footer,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,head,header,hgroup,hr,html,i,iframe,img,input,ins,kbd,label,legend,li,link,main,map,mark,menu,meta,meter,nav,noscript,object,ol,optgroup,option,output,p,param,picture,pre,progress,q,rp,rt,ruby,s,samp,script,section,select,slot,small,source,span,strong,style,sub,summary,sup,table,tbody,td,template,textarea,tfoot,th,thead,time,title,tr,track,u,ul,var,video,wbr"

Comment: Thanks for that, please if you could upvote this, so this doesn't go down the drain

Answer (score 0):

You could just take a list from a site like w3scools, so, I did. I needed this anyway and had it lying around in a project. It is an array of all the HTML elements as of today (Feb 8, 2023).

```js
const HTMLElements = [
    "!DOCTYPE",
    "a",
    "abbr",
    "abbr",
    "acronym", // NOT HTML5
    "address",
    //"applet", // NOT HTML5 (NOT MAJORLY SUPPORTED)
    "area",
    "article",
    "aside",
    "audio",
    "b",
    "base",
    "basefont", // NOT HTML5
    "bdi",
    "bdo",
    "big", // NOT HTML5
    "blockquote",
    "body",
    "br",
    "button",
    "canvas",
    "caption",
    "center", // NOT HTML5
    "cite",
    "code",
    "col",
    "colgroup",
    "data",
    "datalist",
    "dd",
    "del",
    "details",
    "dfn",
    "dialog",
    //"dir", NOT HTML5 (use "ul" instead)
    "div",
    "dl",
    "dt",
    "em",
    "embed",
    "fieldset",
    "figcaption",
    "figure",
    //"font", // NOT HTML5 (use CSS)
    "footer",
    "form",
    //"frame", // NOT HTML5
    //"frameset", // NOT HTML5
    "h1",
    "h2",
    "h3",
    "h4",
    "h5",
    "h6",
    "head",
    "header",
    "hr",
    "html",
    "i",
    "iframe",
    "img",
    "input",
    "ins",
    "kbd",
    "label",
    "legend",
    "li",
    "link",
    "main",
    "map",
    "mark",
    "meta",
    "meter",
    "nav",
    //"noframes", // NOT HTML5
    "noscript",
    "object",
    "ol",
    "optgroup",
    "option",
    "output",
    "p",
    "param",
    "picture",
    "pre",
    "progress",
    "q",
    "rp",
    "rt",
    "ruby",
    "s",
    "samp",
    "script",
    "section",
    "select",
    "small",
    "source",
    "span",
    //"strike", NOT HTML5 (Use <del> or <s> instead)
    "strong",
    "style",
    "sub",
    "summary",
    "sup",
    "svg",
    "table",
    "tbody",
    "td",
    "template",
    "textarea",
    "tfoot",
    "th",
    "thead",
    "time",
    "title",
    "tr",
    "track",
    //"tt", // NOT HTML5 (Use CSS)
    "u",
    "ul",
    "var",
    "video",
    "wbr"
] // Total of 116 (excluding non-html5 and also comments, which are "<!-- [comment] -->").
```

Comment: Note: I did remove the non-html5 elements, at least the ones that no longer work in Chrome/Firefox