# how to get all the data of html body tags to ending body tags in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

same type of question: [Get all elements in the body tag using pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823264/get-all-elements-in-the-body-tag-using-pure-javascript)

I have a very large HTML, CSS and javascript code in the HTML file
so, I want to show them in short cut ways

suppose;

```
<body>
   <div class="w3-red">
       <h1> this is <h1>
   </div>
   <div class="w3-red">
       <h1> this is <h1>
   </div>
   <div class="w3-red">
       <h1> this is <h1>
   </div>
</body>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I want to capture the data inside the HTML body tag in javascript and assign to the variable

The assign to variable result is same as above code

Here is the javascript code

```
<script>
   var myCollection = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
     "The innerHTML of the second paragraph is: " +
     myCollection[2].innerHTML;
</script>
```

Comment: What do you need exactly? Doesn't your provided code work as expected?

Comment: If I put 1 in e thmyCollection[1] then I will get only one div and it doesn't work beside that

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could help you, if you take a look into :

```
 $("body").get(); //Returns a body Object

$("body").get()[0].children //Returns all html tags directly below the body tag
```