# Can I get all html elements by arrary of current page in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to get all elements of current page in chrome extension.
manifest.json looks like the following:

```
{
    "content_scripts": [
        "matches": [
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "backend/generalSites.js"
        ],
        "all_frames": true
    ]
}
```

When I am using document.all[0].outerHTML in the generalSites.js like the following, it only shows section and scirpt tags. What I really want to get is body elements.

```
console.log(document.all[0].outerHTML);
```

Could you help me?

Comment: *"it only shows head section and script tags"* in the above sentence :)

Comment: Judging by the answer this is [Get all elements in the body tag using pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12823264)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command instead of document.all[0].outerHTML

```
document.body.getElementByTagName("*");
```