# How to convert a web API's response from HTML tags' format to JSON

Tags: html, json, cordova, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am working on estimating coding-effort for an application that we'd build either in `PhoneGap` (for Hybrid Dev) or `Xcode`/`Eclipse` (for Native Dev). Now, the part where I am stuck is...
I am hitting a web-API *(right now using the `REST-Client`, before final implementation in the code)* and getting the following response after successful hit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Thing : DataTable Service Definition: getNumber</title>
</head>

<body>
    <br>
    `
    <link href='/abc/css/xyz.css' rel='Stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta content='text/html' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
    <meta content='no-cache, no-store' http-equiv='cache-control'>
    <meta content='-1' http-equiv='expires'>
    <meta content='no-cache, no-store' http-equiv='pragma'><img src=
    "/abc/images/xyzLogo.png"><br>

    <h1>Thing : DataTable Service Definition: getNumber</h1>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>description</th>

            <th>name</th>

            <th>parameterDefinitions</th>

            <th>resultType</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>

            <td>getNumber</td>

            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>baseType</th>

                        <th>description</th>

                        <th>name</th>

                        <th>bishop</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>STRING</td>

                        <td></td>

                        <td>param1</td>

                        <td>1.0</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>STRING</td>

                        <td></td>

                        <td>param2</td>

                        <td>2.0</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>DATETIME</td>

                        <td></td>

                        <td>param3</td>

                        <td>3.0</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>DATETIME</td>

                        <td></td>

                        <td>param4</td>

                        <td>4.0</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>

            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>baseType</th>

                        <th>description</th>

                        <th>name</th>

                        <th>bishop</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>INFOTABLE</td>

                        <td></td>

                        <td>result</td>

                        <td>0.0</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>`<br>
    <br>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

and since I am acquainted with *JSON serialization/parsing*, I am looking for a way to convert this API-response from `HTML` tags' format to `JSON` format.

I feel I am just a line or two away from what I need, but then, don't know what am I missing or not aware of...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map HTML to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980648/map-html-to-json)

Comment: Not exactly @MerianosNikos because it basically looks like a big long cut to a nearby solution.

For one, I'm looking (right now) for a way to convert this response on the REST-Client browser add-on.
Secondly, looking for something like a change/usage of a param that may do it for me. Like, _for instance,_ they've written `text\xml` in the theory part of the _possible duplicate_ you've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Only primitive values (strings, dates, booleans, numbers) and objects and array structures are possible to serialize into JSON. This mean that other host-objects possibles in HTML are not serializable.

In short, JSON is limited to data ('information').

So... is not easy to do what you want

You can do like this:

If the page is in XHTML (a variant of HTML that conforms to XML syntax - i.e. all elements have open and close tags, all attributes have quoted values etc.) then you don't even need to do the HTML to XML conversion first. But you'd get a JSON document that has the same structure as the HTML, for example:

Hello World

Some text

converts to:

"html": { "head": { "title": "Hello World" }, "body": { "p": "Some text" } }

Comment: Thanks @JoaoMarcos, but I needed only that particular data in the JSON format.

Comment: if my answer is useful please aprove them. Tks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I conveyed it last time itself. It's okay what you wrote, but I didn't get what I wanted/needed.