# CKEditor JSON Output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ckeditor

Is it possible for me to get a JSON representation of the contents of a CKEditor instance?

I know about `getData()` but I want to know if I can get a JSON representation.

If not, what is the best way to parse the contents of `getContents()`, because I need it in a JSON format to interact with another system that I don't control.

Update: Let's say I want to type

> Hello, **how** are you?

`getData()` returns this:

`<p>Hello,&nbsp;<strong>how</strong>&nbsp;are you?</p>`

I want this (specific format of the JSON is not important):

`[{"text":"Hello, "},{"text":"how","bold":true},{"text":" are you?"}]`

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are wanting to accomplish. The contents can be assigned to any variable or object property

Comment: Added some clarification

Comment: if specific format is not important, what is important? you mean that it may be a different kind of conversion to json? means that you do not have an specific inside json spec?

Comment: Yes, the format of the JSON is not important.

Comment: Same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980648/map-html-to-json