# how to get the value of html and join together to Json?

Tags: html, json, parsing, html-parsing, converters

I search some keywords but can not find the way to solve my problem.

HTML construct is like the below:

```
<tr>
<span class="originalAirportId">123</span>
<span class="airportName">123</span>
<span class="cityName">123</span>
<span class="provinceName">123</span>
<span class="provinceId">123</span>
<span class="countryId">123</span>
<span class="countryName">123</span>
</tr>
<tr>
<span class="originalAirportId">123</span>
<span class="airportName">123</span>
<span class="cityName">123</span>
<span class="provinceName">123</span>
<span class="provinceId">123</span>
<span class="countryId">123</span>
<span class="countryName">123</span>
</tr>
.....
.....
.....
```

I am not sure how many  tags here.

And required to get .Json like this:

```
{
    "airportList": [
        {
            "originalAirportId": "123",
            "airportName": "asdf",
            "cityName": "qwer",
            "cityId": "qwer",
            "provinceName": "qwer",
            "provinceId": "qwer",
            "countryId": "qwer",
            "countryName": "qwer"
        },
        {
            "originalAirportId": "123",
            "airportName": "asdf",
            "cityName": "qwer",
            "cityId": "qwer",
            "provinceName": "qwer",
            "provinceId": "qwer",
            "countryId": "qwer",
            "countryName": "qwer"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map HTML to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980648/map-html-to-json)