# Recursive methods using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion

I'm trying to replicate the json stringify method but instead use recursion. I've been able to pass alot of test cases but when it comes to nested arrays I seem to be having issues. if there's any empty array inside an array ('[]'), i get something like [,7,9] instead of [[],7,9]. Also if I pass in:

```js
stringifyJSON([[["test","mike",4,["jake"]],3,4]])
"[[test,mike,4,jake,3,4]]"
```

I thought I was close in getting this to work, but I might have to start over. Do you guys have any ideas on what I might be able to change to make this work for nested examples? Here's the code I have now:

```js
var testarray = [9,[[],2,3]] //should return '[9,[[],2,3]]'
var count = 0
var stringifyJSON = function(obj,stack) {
 var typecheck = typeof obj;
 var resarray = stack;
 if(resarray == null){ //does resarray exist? Is this the first time through?
  var resarray = [];
 }
 if(typeof obj === "string"){ //Is obj a string?
  return '"' + String(obj) + '"';
 }

 if((Array.isArray(obj)) && (obj.length > 0)){  //If not a string, is it an object?
  for(var i = 0; i<obj.length;i++){
   if(Array.isArray(obj[i])){
    var arraytemp = []
    stringifyJSON(arraytemp.push(obj[i]),resarray)   // this is probably incorrect, this is how i handle a nested array situation
   }
   if(typeof obj[i] === 'number'){  //if the number is inside of the array, don't quote it
    resarray.push(obj[i]);
   }
   else if(typecheck === 'object' && Array.isArray(obj[0])){
    resarray.push('[' + obj[i] + ']');
   }
   else{
    resarray.push('"' + obj[i] + '"');
   }
   
   obj.shift()  //delete the first object in the array and get ready to recurse to get to the second object.
   stringifyJSON(obj,resarray);  //remember the new array when recursing by passing it into the next recursive instance
  }
 }

 if(obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object'){ //is obj an object?
  for(var key in obj){
   stringifyJSON(resarray.push(key + '"' + ':' + obj[key]),resarray)
  }
  

 }
 if(typeof obj === "number" || obj == null || obj === true || obj === false){ //special cases and if it's a number
  return '' + obj + ''
 }
 if(typecheck === 'object'){ //a special case where you have an empty array that needs to be quoted.
  return '['+resarray+']'
 }
 return '' + resarray.join('') + '';

 

};

//JSON values cannot be a function, a date, or undefined
```

Comment: i haven't gone through the code, but woudlnt' you need to return when calling your recursive function? eg `return stringifyJSON(...)`

Comment: It's a fun problem to try and solve, but make sure it's just for exercise and not something that you would actually use – I've provided many details in my answer below. If you have any questions, I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you guys have any ideas on what I might be able to change to make this work for nested examples?

Sure, but it's going to scrap you entire function, so I hope you don't mind. I'll provide a bullet-list of points why this approach is essential and yours is essentially *flawed* from the get-go **:(**

---

**Corner cases**

This function does a simple case analysis on a non-null data's `constructor` property and encodes accordingly. It manages to cover a lot of corner cases that you're unlikely to consider, such as

- `JSON.stringify(undefined)` returns `undefined`
- `JSON.stringify(null)` returns `'null'`
- `JSON.stringify(true)` returns `'true'`
- `JSON.stringify([1,2,undefined,4])` returns `'[1,2,null,4]'`
- `JSON.stringify({a: undefined, b: 2})` returns `'{ "b": 2 }'`
- `JSON.stringify({a: /foo/})` returns `{ "a": {} }`

So to verify that our `stringifyJSON` function actually works properly, I'm not going to test the output of it directly. Instead, I'm going to write a little `test` method that ensures the `JSON.parse` of our encoded JSON actually returns our original input value

```
// we really only care that JSON.parse can work with our result
// the output value should match the input value
// if it doesn't, we did something wrong in our stringifier
const test = data => {
  return console.log(JSON.parse(stringifyJSON(data)))
}

test([1,2,3])     // should return [1,2,3]
test({a:[1,2,3]}) // should return {a:[1,2,3]}
```

> **Disclaimer:** it should be obvious that the code I'm about to share is **not meant to be used as an actual replacement** for `JSON.stringify` – there's countless corner cases we probably didn't address. Instead, this code is shared to provide a demonstration for how we could go about such a task. Additional corner cases could easily be added to this function.

---

**Runnable demo**

Without further ado, here is `stringifyJSON` in a runnable demo that verifies excellent compatibility for several common cases

```js
const stringifyJSON = data => {
  if (data === undefined)
    return undefined
  else if (data === null)
    return 'null'
  else if (data.constructor === String)
    return '"' + data.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"'
  else if (data.constructor === Number)
    return String(data)
  else if (data.constructor === Boolean)
    return data ? 'true' : 'false'
  else if (data.constructor === Array)
    return '[ ' + data.reduce((acc, v) => {
      if (v === undefined)
        return [...acc, 'null']
      else
        return [...acc, stringifyJSON(v)]
    }, []).join(', ') + ' ]'
  else if (data.constructor === Object)
    return '{ ' + Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, k) => {
      if (data[k] === undefined)
        return acc
      else
        return [...acc, stringifyJSON(k) + ':' + stringifyJSON(data[k])]
    }, []).join(', ') + ' }'
  else
    return '{}'
}

// round-trip test and log to console
const test = data => {
  return console.log(JSON.parse(stringifyJSON(data)))
}

test(null)                               // null
test('he said "hello"')                  // 'he said "hello"'
test(5)                                  // 5
test([1,2,true,false])                   // [ 1, 2, true, false ]
test({a:1, b:2})                         // { a: 1, b: 2 }
test([{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}])                // [ { a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 } ]
test({a:[1,2,3], c:[4,5,6]})             // { a: [ 1, 2, 3 ], c: [ 4, 5, 6 ] }
test({a:undefined, b:2})                 // { b: 2 }
test([[["test","mike",4,["jake"]],3,4]]) // [ [ [ 'test', 'mike', 4, [ 'jake' ] ], 3, 4 ] ]
```

---

***"So why is this better?"***

- this works for more than just Array types – we can stringify Strings, Numbers, Arrays, Objects, Array of Numbers, Arrays of Objects, Objects containing Arrays of Strings, even `null`s and `undefined`s, and so on – you get the idea
- each case of our `stringifyJSON` object is like a little program that tells us exactly how to encode each type (eg `String`, `Number`, `Array`, `Object` etc)
- no whacked out `typeof` type checking – after we check for the `undefined` and `null` cases, we know we can try to read the `constructor` property.
- no manual looping where we have to mentally keep track of counter variables, how/when to increment them
- no complex `if` conditions using `&&`, `||`, `!`, or checking things like `x > y.length` etc
- no use of `obj[0]` or `obj[i]` that stresses our brain out
- no assumptions about Arrays/Objects being empty – and *without* having to check the `length` property
- no other mutations for that matter – that means we don't have to think about some master return value `resarray` or what state it's in after `push` calls happen at various stages in the program

---

**Custom objects**

`JSON.stringify` allows us to set a `toJSON` property on our custom objects so that when we stringify them, we will get the result we want.

```js
const Foo = x => ({
  toJSON: () => ({ type: 'Foo', value: x })
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(Foo(5)))
// {"type":"Foo","value":5}
```

We could easily add this kind of functionality to our code above – changes in **bold**

```
const stringifyJSON = data => {
  if (data === undefined)
    return undefined
  else if (data === null)
    return 'null'
  else if (data.toJSON instanceof Function)
    return stringifyJSON(data.toJSON())
  ...
  else
    return '{}'
}

test({toJSON: () => ({a:1, b:2})})  // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around with your code, I found that if you replace:

`resarray.push('[' + obj[i] + ']');`

with:

`resarray.push(stringifyJSON(obj[i]))` it works well with the arrays and still satisfies your recursive process.

Also I found a few quirks with running it through objects like `{ hello: 5, arr: testarray, arr2: [1, 2,3, "hello"], num: 789, str: '4444', str2: "67494" };` and found that by changing the stringifying of objects from:

`stringifyJSON(resarray.push(key + '"' + ':' + obj[key]),resarray)`

to something more like:

`stringifyJSON(resarray.push('"' + key + '"' + ':' + stringifyJSON(obj[key])),resarray);`

it should workout more of how you want. This is really cool though and I had fun playing around with it!