# Trying to replicate JSON.stringify

Tags: arrays, json, object, recursion

Okay so I am trying to replicate JSON.stringify. Currently I am getting this error. Unfortunately this error is not very helpful because the message is cut short before it actually gets to what the problem is so I am quite stuck. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my object code? I am currently commenting out the recusive code for nested arrays/objects as the tests for that are separate. [image: error]
Here is the code (only the code relevant to arrays and objects):

```
if (Array.isArray(input)) {
  var toJSON = '[';
  var key = 0;
  function toString() {

    if (input.length === 0) {
      return '[]';
    }

    if (key < input.length) {

      // if (Array.isArray(input[key]) || typeof input[key] === 'object') {
      //   toJSON += stringifier(input[key]);
      // }
      if (input[key] === null || typeof input[key] === 'function' || input[key] === undefined) {
        toJSON += 'null';
      }
      if (typeof input[key] === 'number' || typeof input[key] === 'boolean') {
        toJSON += `${input[key]}`;
      }
      if (typeof input[key] === 'string') {
        toJSON += `"${input[key]}"`;
      }
      key++;
      if (key < input.length) {
        toJSON += ',';
      }
      toString();
    }
  }
  toString();
  return toJSON + ']';
}

if (typeof input === 'object') {
  if (Object.keys(input).length === 0) {
    return '{}';
  }

  var toJSON = '{';
  for (var key in input) {
    toJSON += `"${key}":`;
    // if (Array.isArray(input[key]) || typeof input[key] === 'object') {
    //   toJSON += stringifier(input[key]);
    // }
    if (input[key] === null || input[key] === undefined || typeof input[key] === 'function') {
      toJSON += `null`;
    } else if (typeof input[key] === 'number') {
      toJSON += `${input[key]}`;
    } else if (typeof input[key] === 'string') {
      toJSON += `"${input[key]}"`;
    }
    if (key != Object.keys(input)[Object.keys(input).length - 1]) {
      toJSON += ',';
    }
  }
  return toJSON + '}';
}
```

Now if I uncomment the recursive code, it breaks the array code that is currently working and I get this: [image: error 2]

Comment: *"this error is not very helpful ..."*: but you can just output `input` to the console to verify for which input it didn't work, right? And you can produce the correct result with the native `JSON.stringify`, right? So what is the difference? There are hundreds of reasons why it could not work, since you don't deal with any special characters in strings (for example).

Comment: What test suite are you using, can you attach a debugger and inspect the actual values at that respective assertion?  And please provide a minimal reproducible example. Ie provide the input for which the testcase is failing and how you call your serializer ...

Comment: see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42690135/633183) for a runnable implementation

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code

1. in your object serialization (and seemingly also in your testcases) you forgot to handle `boolean`s. Ie, you will output the property's name, but not its value. Thus

   ```
   stringifier({"a": true})
   ```

   will produce an output of `{"a": }` which is obviously wrong
2. You are serializing `undefined` to `null`. That's not standard behaviour. Not sure whether your project is defined that way, but

   ```
    JSON.stringify({"a": undefined})
   ```

   will produce `{}` whereas your code produces `{"a": null}`
3. In both of your code parts (ie for arrays and for objects) you are checking

   ```
    if (... || typeof input[key] === 'object')
       toJson += stringifier(input[key]);
   ```

   in the very beginning. The problem with that is, that `typeof null === "object"` ie, your recursive call will get an input of `null` which probably leads to erroneous results.

   I'd suggest to handle all primitives (`number`, `string`, `boolean`, `undefined`, `null`) first. And only if none of them applies, treat it as object or array ...
4. For adding the comma, I'd suggest a different approach. Instead of checking if there is an additional element/property to handle and add the comma at the end of the current iteration's body, move this code to the beginning of the iteration and check if the current iteration is the very first iteration.

   ```
    let first = true;
    for (let key in input) {
      if (!first) toJson += ',';
      first = false;
      toJSON += `"${key}":`;
      ...
    }
   ```
5. You may need special treat for some special objects like `Date` or `Error`, because handling them like standard objects may lead to undesired results. Ie for instance

   ```
    JSON.stringify(new Date());
   ```

   produces an ISO date string like `"2023-07-06T13:08:29.460Z"`

And just as a general remark: It would probably be better, to just handle the `Array` and `object` specific parts separately and handle the serialization of primitive values in a single point. Ie currently you have to duplicate the code for serializing `number`, `string` or `boolean` which reduces maintainability and is (as your case shows) error prone. I'd suggest something like the following.

```
function serialize(input, inarray) {
  switch (typeof input) {
    case "number":
    case "boolean": 
      return `${input}`;
    case "string":
      return `"${input.replace(/"/g, '\\"')}"`;
    case "undefined":
      //special behaviour of JSON.serialize 
      //it will serialize undefined array elements as "null"
      return inarray ? "null" : undefined;
    case "function":
      //functions don't show up in serialization output
      return undefined;

     //for the behaviour in your code, ie null, undefined and function
     //all being serialzed to null, you can just use the following
     //case "function":
     //case "undefined":
     //  return "null";
  }

  if (input === null)
    return "null";

  //now you can be sure, it's an object or array

  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    let s = "["; let first = true;
    for (let e of input) {
      let ser = serialize(e, true);
      if (ser === undefined) 
        continue;
      if (!first) s+=", ";
      first = false;
      s += serialize(e);
    }
    return s + "]";
  } else {
    let s = "{"; let first = true;
    for (let k in input) {
      let ser = serialize(input[k]);
      if (ser === undefined)
        continue;

      if (!first) s+=","; 
      first = false;
      s += `"${k}": ${ser}`;
    }
    return s + "}";
  }
}
```

It's quick and dirty. There may be some issues with special cases, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript datum are represented with objects (compound) and primitive data elements which can be nested to any conceivable depth. A recursive procedure is best suited to match the recursive structure of the input data.

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutation, variable reassignments, and other side effects. In the code below, we perform a simple type analysis of the input `t`, and immediately return the computed JSON representation -

```js
function serialize(t) {
  if (t === undefined)
    return undefined
  else if (t === null)
    return 'null'
  else if (t.constructor === String)
    return '"' + t.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"'
  else if (t.constructor === Number)
    return String(t)
  else if (t.constructor === Boolean)
    return t ? 'true' : 'false'
  else if (t.constructor === Date)
    return t.toISOString()
  else if (t.constructor === Array)
    return '[' + t.map(v =>
      v === undefined ? 'null' : serialize(v)
    ).join(',') + ']'
  else if (t.constructor === Object)
    return '{' + Object.keys(t).flatMap(k =>
      t[k] === undefined
        ? []
        : [serialize(k) + ':' + serialize(t[k])]
    ).join(',') + '}'
  else
    throw Error(`cannot serialize unsupported type: ${t}`)
}

console.log(serialize(null))
console.log(serialize('she said "hello"'))
console.log(serialize(5))
console.log(serialize([1,2,"three",true,false]))
console.log(serialize({a:1,b:2,c:new Date}))
console.log(serialize([{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}]))
console.log(serialize({a:[1,2,3],c:[4,5,6,{seven:8}]}))
console.log(serialize({a:undefined,b:2}))
console.log(serialize([[["alice","bob",4,["charlie"]],3,4]]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42690135/633183) for the original implementation.