# JSON displayed in the website body instead of the source-code. How to read it with android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, json

I'm trying to read in my android app JSON data from a website that returns JSON data with this code (in javascript):

```
 document.body.innerHTML = "<pre style='word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;'>" + JSON.stringify(address, null, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Example website can be found here: [Link](http://glesports.eu/api/scripts.html)

The problem is that fetching this website from android would return me the full html source-code instead of giving me only the body with the JSON data.

The code in android to fetch this would look like this:

```
URL url = new URL(apiURL);
connection =  url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(line+"\n");
    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);  
}
```

So I don't know how to manage this... I can modify both, the website html or the android app, but I've tried everything and I didn't find a solution.

Can someone help?

Comment: you can use jsoup  to parse html

Comment: is the website address returning JSON response like https://www.reddit.com/.json or only html content ?.

Comment: @Popeye It returns JSON in the body (a normal user would see a JSON in the website) but if you check the source code it shows all the HTML code. When I use the .getInputStream function in android, it reads the HTML code insetad of reading the JSON delivered by the web page. Here you have an example: [link](http://glesports.eu/api/scripts.html)

Comment: See this would help https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980648/map-html-to-json&ved=0ahUKEwiR4r-pja_XAhVSySYKHXUyDQsQFggxMAE&usg=AOvVaw0Y-gQnYa3J9H3KwyGZF3ep. After converting it to Json, retrieve the value by the key of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the unwanted HTML

```
URL url = new URL(apiURL);
connection =  url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(line+"\n");
    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);  
}
// remove <pre> tag
line = line.replace("<pre style='word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;'>","").replace("</pre>","");
```