# Defining a function to apply only to a subset of properties of the objects passed as argument

Tags: javascript, function, object, arguments

I recently came across [this nifty piece of JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980648/map-html-to-json/44293677#44293677)

and I am struggling a bit to understand how it works, and specifically this part :

```
  Array.from(e.attributes, ({name, value}) => [name, value])
```

Here, we deal with a [NamedNodeMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap) which is a collection of Attr objects, and an Attr does have properties named `name` and `value` among many others. 
So, we have an anonymous function that takes an object and returns an array. So far, so good.

What I don't quite get is the way the argument of the function is defined as the litteral object `{name, value}`.

I was able to isolate the behavior :

```
> o={ a: 1, b: 2, ldfk: 'mùl' }
> let objToArr = function({a,b}){ return [a,b] }

> objToArr(o)
[ 1, 2 ]
> 
> o = {'dfklj':3.14, 'c':'z', 'a':1, 'foo':'bar', 'b':2, 'z':26 }
{ dfklj: 3.14, c: 'z', a: 1, foo: 'bar', b: 2, z: 26 }
> objToArr(o)
[ 1, 2 ]
>
```

but I still don't understand *why* it works. Could someone please explain or refer me to the appropriate documentation ?

Comment: your first link does not work.

Comment: link fixe, thanks Nina

Comment: It's called [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Also: [Unpacking fields from objects passed as function parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)

Comment: Thanks adiga, that's the answer I was looking for. JavaScript never ceases to amaze me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), where an object is assigned to an object literal with only the keys, you need to take.

```js
var object = { name_: 'foo', value: 42 },
    { name_, value } = object;           // name is a property of window

console.log(name_);
console.log(value);
```

Comment: Bingo ! (proceeding to compute the true answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything )

Answer (score 1):

Your not exactly defining an object literal as an argument, but rather you are [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the object. You can think of deconstruction as another way of accessing the properties of an object.

For example, if you have an object `a`:

```
const a = {
  name: 'foo',
  value: 'bar'
}
```

You can get its properties in a number of different ways:

Through bracket notation:

```
const name = a["name"];
const value = a["value"];
```

Via dot notation:

```
const name = a.name;
const value = a.value;
```

Or via [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const {name, value} = a; // name & value are variables which you can use
```

```js
const a = {
  name: "foo",
  value: "bar"
}

var name = a["name"];
var value = a["value"];
console.log(name, value);

var name = a.name;
var value = a.value;
console.log(name, value);

var {name, value} = a;
console.log(name, value);
```

Thus, when you use `{name, value}` in your function arguments, you are effectively telling javascript to extract the `name` and `value` properties from the object passed in as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't quite get is the way the argument of the function is defined as the litteral object {name, value}.

This is called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

Comment: No, it's not an "assignment" when used in the parameter declaration of a function.

Comment: You can assign to new variables even if its used in the function. `const func = ({a: foo, b: bar}) => {console.log(foo, bar)}` [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names)