# Checking number of times CSS classes called.

Tags: css

I was thinking of writing a script which would tell me:

- How often each CSS class defined in my .css file is used in my code
- Redundant CSS classes - classes never used
- CSS classes hat are referenced that don't exist.

But I just want to make sure something like this doesn't exist already? Does it?

Thanks

Comment: I think PhpStorm/WebStorm has a "Find Usages" feature which should be able to locate where they're used and I *think* it will highlight unused classes for simpler projects. Visual Studio might even do the same.

Comment: Many CSS validators can tell you some of the features you are asking for.

Comment: You can also use Chrome's Audit tool that tells you what classes are being used in the current page.
Or, CSS Usage for Firebug.

Comment: If you did want to write one, use a HTML parser to extract class attributes, split on spaces, and count occurances.  For CSS, remove comments, replace `\{[^}]*\}` with `,`, match `\.(\w+)`, and you have your class selectors.  You can then figure out which class selectors are used in HTML vs CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, I wrote one.

### [try it](http://jsfiddle.net/j89W6/2/)

First we need to find our style sheet.  In an actual script, this would be written better, but this works on jsFiddle.

```
var styles = document.head.getElementsByTagName('style');
var css = styles[styles.length - 1].innerHTML;
```

Then remove comments, and the bodies of each selector (i.e. the stuff between the brackets).  This is done because there could be a `.com` in a background-image property, or any number of other problems.  We assume there isn't a `}` in a literal string, so that would cause problems.

```
var clean = css.replace(/\/\*.*?\*\//g, '').replace(/\{[^}]*\}/g, ',');
```

We can find classes with regular expressions, and then count how many of them occur.

```
var re_class = /\.(\w+)/g;
var cssClasses = {},  match, c;
while (match = re_class.exec(clean)) {
    c = match[1];
    cssClasses[c] = cssClasses[c] + 1 || 1;
}
```

I used [jsprint](http://brigand.github.io/jsprint/) for displaying our findings.  This shows how many times each class is mentioned in our CSS.

```
jsprint("css classes used", cssClasses);
```

Thanks to Google and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4256372/1074592) we can find all elements in the body, and loop through them.  By default, we assume no classes were used in our HTML, and all classes used were defined.

```
var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
var neverUsed = Object.keys(cssClasses);
var neverDefined = [];
var htmlClasses = {};
```

We get each elements class, and split it on the spaces.

```
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var e = elements[i];
    var classes = (e.className || "").split(" ");
```

This is a three dimensional loop, but it works nicely.

```
    for (var j=0; j<classes.length; j++) {
        for (var k=0; k<neverUsed.length; k++) {
```

We thought `classes[j]` was never used, but we found a use of it.  Remove it from the array.

```
            if (neverUsed[k] === classes[j]) {
                neverUsed.splice(k, 1);
            }
        }
```

It looks like we found a class that doesn't appear in our CSS.  We just need to make sure it's not an empty string, and then push it onto our array.

```
        if (classes[j].length && cssClasses[classes[j]] == null) {
            neverDefined.push(classes[j]);
        }
```

Also count the number of times each class is used in HTML.

```
        if (classes[j].length) {
            htmlClasses[classes[j]] = htmlClasses[classes[j]] + 1 || 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Then display our results.

```
jsprint("html class usage", htmlClasses);
jsprint("never used in HTML", neverUsed);
jsprint("never defined in CSS", neverDefined);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Why is it saying `a` was used once when it is not :/