# Finding background color of page or page view using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a JS newbie with a complex problem. I want to find out the background color of any webpage. The problem is sometime it is defined in the body tag, sometimes in inline or external css and in a more complex example some websites don't set background color on body (in some cases they do as well) but put a DIV that covers the whole page. So my problem is I want to find out the background color of the whole view. Can someone please help me.

I already tried to search before posting this question but I only found ways to get the body color not the background of the whole view so please don't mark it duplicate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just work your way through each one. Its not that hard. If body has background..... else if first div has background.... etc.

Comment: thanks Ruddy, but I have few examples where background color is defined in the body but the div covering up the page has some other background color.

Comment: Check out the answer to this question it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256339/javascript-how-to-loop-through-all-dom-elements-on-a-page

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a complete answer, since there are so many variables involved. How does it know a `div` that covers the whole page is for the background? Getting the background colour from the body tag, whether `inline` or in an `external` stylesheet is pretty trivial however.

Comment: Hi a4arpan! Do we know what is the markup of the pages? Do we consider background only if the element has at least 100% width and 100% height? In case there are CSS3 gradients on the background, should it be taken as well?

Comment: @a4arpan See also [Get the document's background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543197/get-the-documents-background-color/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pure javascript or jquery to achieve what you want. To do what you want you can use this functions

Find by tagname:

```
function getBackgroundByTagName(tag){
    var color =  $(tag).css('background-color');
    console.log(color);
}
```

Find by class:

```
function getBackgroundByClassName(classname){
    var color =  $('.'+classname).css('background-color');
    console.log(color);
}
```

Find by id

```
function getBackgroundById(idofelement){
    var color =  $('.'+idofelement).css('background-color');
    console.log(color);
}
```

All you need to do is to run any of the functions and it will show the color in console.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a start. This will get the `background-colour` of the `<body>` tag, whether it's `inline` or in an external `stylesheet`.

```
function getBackground() {

    var getBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
    var prop = window.getComputedStyle(getBody).getPropertyValue("background-color");

    if (prop === "transparent") {
        console.log("No background colour set")
    } else {
        console.log(prop);
    }
}

getBackground();
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2VaXj/)**

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could use a canvas element to draw the web page into it and then examine a particular pixel to see what colour it was:

1. Get all the DOM elements and draw then to a canvas: [Mozilla - Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas)

Using script you'd need to clone the contents of the page in question, and then paste it into a canvas element.

2. Get the pixel colour: [Stack Overflow - get-pixel-color-from-canvas-on-mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735470/get-pixel-color-from-canvas-on-mouseover)

You could choose the coordinates with the mouse pointer, or you could simple hard code a specific pixel (in the corner of the page perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

### Make a screenshot and then find the most common color.

#### Is the most common color the same as the background?

You can visit a couple of websites and see if it is true. I guess for all practical purposes it is. Also this method can handle cases where an image is used as a background. And even for difficult cases like [these](http://line25.com/articles/interesting-web-design-trend-vertical-split-layouts) it's better and much more simple than trying to deduce color from relations of nested blocks. Although it may give incorrect results for gradients, pattern backgrounds, and rich color variations.

#### How to automate screenshots?

You can use PhantomJS to capture the screenshot and then save it as a png file. [This page](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) should explain the details. Don't forget to [lower viewport resolution](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html) to reduce amount of work.

#### How to find the most common color?

You can do it using [NodeJS](https://github.com/elad/node-imagemagick-native), [Python](https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/ex.html), [PHP](http://php.net/manual/book.imagick.php), or any language that have appropriate tools. Just traverse the pixels, store color frequencies in a hash table and then find the key associated with the maximum value. In pseudocode:

```
table = new HashTable()

# Count the colors
for pixel in pixels:
    if pixel.color not in table.keys:
        table[pixel.color] = 0
    table[pixel.color]++

# Find the color associated with the max count
result = table[table.keys[0]]
for color in table.keys:
    if table[color] > table[result]:
        result = color

print(result)
```

You could break the image into 10x10 blocks and pick one pixel from each to reduce the amount of computation but low resolution did the same job already, even better: there are also less IO.

#### How to put these parts together?

PhantomJS has [NodeJS API](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node) so you can parse pages and find background colors in a single script. For other languages you can call PhantomJS command as an external process and wait until it finishes. Related docs for [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html). Or just Bash, it should be even simpler if you can do Bash scripting.