# Is there a line of javascript that will change every hex color to a different hex color?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, hex

Basically, I'm wondering if it's possible to have a line of javascript isolate a specific hex code on a page (lets say #1166e7) and change it to another hex code (lets say #ff0000).

I know that this is a weird question because the process could easily be done by just changing the css, but in my situation, just pretend I can't access the css.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Don't quite understand your question. You are trying to find all the color with #1166e7 and change it with #ff0000. I know changing an element background color is by:


document.getElementById('myElemID').style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';


where myElemID is the ID of the element you want to change the background color.

Comment: @Mritunjay I haven't tried anything yet :/ I don't actually know if javascript would be the way to go. I made an temp url for an example of what I'm trying to do http://goo.gl/SLlE52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go over all css properties of every element present on the page and replace the value you are looking for. You could do something like:

```
$("*").foreach(function() {
    for(var key in this.style) {
        if(this.style[key] == '#1166e7') {
            this.style[key] = '#ff0000';
        }
    }
});
```

Note that I used the jQuery Framework to select all elements within the page. See [Javascript: How to loop through ALL DOM elements on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256339/javascript-how-to-loop-through-all-dom-elements-on-a-page) for better approaches with wich you can iterate over all elements.