# Check if property of an observable has a bound DOM element

Tags: knockout.js

Is it possible to check if a property of an observable has an element bound to it?

```
<div data-bind="visible: MyObject().property1">Property 1 has a value</div>
<div data-bind="text: MyObject().property1"></div>
</script>    
    var ViewModel = function()
    {
        this.MyObject = ko.observable({property1: "some text", property2: "some other text"});
    }
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

Is there any way to determine if any elements are bound to a property (i.e. `MyObject().property1`) (and if so, which elements? (in this case an array of 2 divs)),  and further, if there are *no* elements bound to a property (i.e. `MyObject().property2`)

Comment: This could help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179058/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-elements-that-use-a-particular-knockout-binding

Comment: Why do you want to know? Any specific feature or behavior you're trying to implement?

Comment: @user3297291, i am trying to pass a list of messages from the server, then display them in particular parts of my view. any message that has a "bound" element should how there, and anything else should show in a summary area. my current solution is to have an additional binding on my "message" elements that then records that element in an array, then when i receive the json response, check if the message is "registered" (i.e. is bound), and if not, add it to another "summary" collection