# Get own text content using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I wan to collect all text from a list of elements obtains using

`var elements =document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");`

What I've done so far:

```js
var text = '';
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  text = text + ' ' + elements[i].innerText
}
```

This will return duplicated text because it get the own text of each element plus its children's. I want to know if there is a way to get element's owntext using pure javasript?

Comment: Try using index in elements. Example: elements[i].innerText

Comment: Would that help if there are nested elements with the same tag?

Comment: Sorry I've made the mistake not inserting index while asking, but the code I used has index already

Comment: Similar discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256339/javascript-how-to-loop-through-all-dom-elements-on-a-page

Comment: It says textContent will include also `<script>`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: Yes, but you're leaving millions of FireFox users without content ... It's easy to check the tag name before using its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that nested matching elements of a particular tag are being counted twice.  The solution is to check if we've already visited a parent element and to skip the child if that's the case.

```
var text = '';
var visited = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var found = false;
  for (var e = elements[i]; e != null; e = e.parentNode) {
    if (visited.indexOf(e) > -1) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    text = text + ' ' + elements[i].innerText;
    visited.push(elements[i]);
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h8k0xx82/

Comment: Note that I updated the solution with a conditional `if (!found)` which should be needed.  Glad to be of help! :)