# How to check how many different tags exist in a page using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to know how many different tags exist in a page?
e.g. html; body; div; td; div; can be counted as 4 different tags.

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: Yes there is a way. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256339/javascript-how-to-loop-through-all-dom-elements-on-a-page

Comment: Curiosity -- why would you need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is YES :

```
const allTagNames = Array.from(   //cast the result to array to be able to use array's utilities  like "map"
      document.querySelectorAll('*') // select all elements in the page
   ).map(node => node.tagName) // get only the tagName

const allTagNamesWithoutDuplication = [...new Set(allTagNames)]  // Remove duplicated tagname
```

And the result will be :

```
allTagNamesWithoutDuplication.length
```

```js
const distinctTags=() => {
      const allTagNames = Array.from(   
          document.querySelectorAll('*') 
       ).map(node => node.tagName.toLowerCase()) 
      
      return [...new Set(allTagNames)]
}


const result = distinctTags();

console.log(
    `this page contains ${result.length}  tags : `, result
   
)
```

Comment: if you're going to map all of the elements anyway, why not just change it to `.reduce` so the end result is unique array as well?

Answer (score 1):

The `document` has a property called `all` which lists all the tags found on the page. Each of these has a `tagName` property which is the tag without angle brackets. It comes in uppercase format, but for simplicity just force all tagNames to be lowercase using the [`.toLowerCase()` String method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase). You can loop through it like I've shown below, storing any tag not yet found on the page, in the `tagsFound` array.

```
var tagsFound= [];
for( var index = 0; index < document.all.length; index++ ) {
    if( tagsFound.indexOf(document.all[index].tagName.toLowerCase() == -1 ) {
        // Tag was not found before this
        tags.push(document.all[index].tagName.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Then, the number of unique tags found would be

```
tagsFound.length
```