# JavaScript code to find text in an HTML body and highlight it FIX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this JavaScript function that takes a string and highlight it in the html page. I'm basically trying to simulate Ctrl-F with initial value string:

**Function**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function highlight(word) {
    var node = document.body;
    for (node = node.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {

        var n = node;
        var match_pos = 0;
        match_pos = n.nodeValue.indexOf(word);
        var before = n.nodeValue.substr(0, match_pos);// split into a part before the match
        var middle = n.nodeValue.substr(match_pos, word.length); // the matched word to preserve case
        var after = document.createTextNode(n.nodeValue.substr(match_pos + word.length));// and the part after the match    
        var highlight_span = document.createElement("span");// create a span in the middle
        highlight_span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        highlight_span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(middle));// insert word as textNode in new span
        n.nodeValue = before; // Turn node data into before
        n.parentNode.insertBefore(after, n.nextSibling); // insert after
        n.parentNode.insertBefore(highlight_span, n.nextSibling); // insert new span
        highlights.push(highlight_span);
        highlight_span.id = "highlight_span" + highlights.length;
        node = node.nextSibling; // Advance to next node or we get stuck in a loop because we created a span (child)


    }
}

</script>
```

Basically, The sentence I give to the function as an argument is not highlighted. Knowing that I'm positive it exists.

**This Loads the HTML page**

```
@Html.Action("GetHtmlPage", "Upload", new { path = Model.documentPath })
```

**Then, This Calls the funtion**

```
@{
    var str = Model.sentence["sentence"].AsString;
    <script>highlight(@str)</script>
}
```

Comment: What happened, what is the issue you try to figure out?

Comment: Basically nothing, The sentence is not highlighted

Comment: I've never seen anybody try to iterate a NodeList like that

Comment: Ugh, Isn't that good enough?

Comment: check you are really iterating by printing the content of the node in the console, also `highlight_span.id = "highlight_span" + highlights.length;` is assigning the same Id to all highlighted spans...

Comment: I'm assuming only one sentence exist in the html document

Comment: @NasriYatim quoting what Sterling Archer wrote, the DOM is a tree, and you just check the first level. So you miss the deep of each branch. Usually it's done with recursive function techniques. To keep all "flat" you could try with this trik: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256339/javascript-how-to-loop-through-all-dom-elements-on-a-page

Comment: no errors? i'd expect to see errors.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with your loop. Something like this will work much better.

```js
var highlights = []
function searchElement(elem, word){
  var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(elem.childNodes);
  for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
    if(children[i].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE){
      var n = children[i];
        var match_pos = n.nodeValue.indexOf(word);
        if(match_pos == -1){
          continue;
         }
        var before = n.nodeValue.substr(0, match_pos);// split into a part before the match
        var middle = n.nodeValue.substr(match_pos, word.length); // the matched word to preserve case
        var after = document.createTextNode(n.nodeValue.substr(match_pos + word.length));// and the part after the match    
        var highlight_span = document.createElement("span");// create a span in the middle
        highlight_span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        highlight_span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(middle));// insert word as textNode in new span
        n.nodeValue = before; // Turn node data into before
        n.parentNode.insertBefore(after, n.nextSibling); // insert after
        n.parentNode.insertBefore(highlight_span, n.nextSibling); // insert new span
        highlights.push(highlight_span);
        highlight_span.id = "highlight_span" + highlights.length;
    }else if(children[i].childNodes.length){
      searchElement(children[i], word);
    }
  }
}
function highlight(word) {
    searchElement(document.body, word)
}

highlight("Even more test");
```

```html
test
<div>
  More test
  
  <span>Even more test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What If I want to highlight a specific sentence in the document at the load time. without asking the user what to highlight?

Comment: For example I know that the html document will contain "Specific String", how can I highlight it instantly without clicking the button?

Comment: It's just a function, you can call the function from wherever. It doesn't have to be on a button click. Check out the edited code snippet.