# JavaScript to trim whitespace from the innerHtml for all elements in a html string

Tags: javascript

I have a string as follows:

```
<div> Here is some text&nbsp;</div>
<div>Here is some text </div>
<ul>
    <li>test 1 </li>
    <li> test 2</li>
    <li>&nbsp;test 3&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<div> Here is some text </div>
```

I need to loop through each element and trim the whitespace and any leading or trailing `&nbsp;` entities using JavaScript so that the end result is as follows:

```
<div>Here is some text</div>
<div>Here is some text</div>
<ul>
    <li>test 1</li>
    <li>test 2</li>
    <li>test 3</li>
</ul>
<div>Here is some text</div>
```

To provide more background, this is a string that is being pasted into a WYSIWYG editor. So I am simply attempting to clean up the string as it is being pasted. I'm not great with JavaScript, but even if I were to use the method suggested in the *Javascript: How to loop through ALL DOM elements on a page?* post, I am uncertain as to how to utilise `document.getElementsByTagName("*");` in a string.

UPDATE
Using @Bharata's answer, I was able to achieve the clean up using the following:

```
var str = "<div> Here is some text&nbsp;</div>" + 
"<div>Here is some text </div>" + 
"<ul>" + 
"    <li>test 1 </li>" + 
"    <li> test 2</li>" + 
"    <li>&nbsp;test 3&nbsp;</li>" + 
"</ul>" + 
"<div> Here is some text </div>";

var cleanHtml = cleanUp(str);

function cleanUp(content) {
    var dom = document.createElement("div");
    dom.innerHTML = content;
    var elems = dom.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].innerHTML) {
            elems[i].innerHTML = elems[i].innerHTML.trim();
        }
    }
    return dom.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to loop through ALL DOM elements on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256339/javascript-how-to-loop-through-all-dom-elements-on-a-page) ... once you have done this, you may simply run `trim()` on the inner HTML of each element.

Comment: I'm not looping through all the elements in a page, but a string.

Comment: What environment are you running in, nodejs? If so that affects how you would do this as you would need (or well should) use a DOM library like jsDOM to parse the string into elements to make it easier in trimming the contents.

Comment: is this being done in browser or other environment?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys - please see my edit.

Comment: this should probably help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JS DOM API for this case like follows:

- Add your text to hidden `div` element
- Replace all spaces in `innerHTML` content using `trim()` and `replace()` functions.

**Full example**

```js
var str = "<div> Here is some text&nbsp;</div>" + 
"<div>Here is some text </div>" + 
"<ul>" + 
"    <li>test 1 </li>" + 
"    <li> test 2</li>" + 
"    <li>&nbsp;test 3&nbsp;</li>" + 
"</ul>" + 
"<div> Here is some text </div>";

var hiddenDiv = document.querySelector('#hidden-div');
hiddenDiv.innerHTML = str;

var hiddenElems = hiddenDiv.getElementsByTagName('*');

for(var i = 0; i < hiddenElems.length; i++)
{
    if(hiddenElems[i].innerHTML)
    {
        hiddenElems[i].innerHTML = hiddenElems[i].innerHTML.trim().replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
    }
}

document.write('<pre>' + hiddenDiv.innerHTML + '</pre>');
```

```html
<div id="hidden-div" style="display:none"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to get all text nodes and trim content:

```
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.querySelector('#my-div'), 
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, 
    null, 
    false
);

var node;

while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
    if(!node.previousSibling)
       node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(/^(&nbsp;|\s)*/, '')

    if(!node.nextSibling)
       node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(/(&nbsp;|\s)*$/, '')
}
```