# How can you find an HTML element on a page purely by the number of characters in its id attribute JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath, attributes

I want to use JavaScript to find a specific HTML element by the number of characters in its `id` attribute.

For example if the element I want to find looks like this:

`<element id="12345678"></element>`

And has 8 characters in its `id` attribute, how would I find this element.

Some basic pseudo code I imagine would look like this:

`[e] = document.GetElementById where id.charLength == 8`

And this would return an array with all elements on the page whose `id` attribute is 8 characters long.

In case anyone asks, I cannot just use the `id` to get the element because the `id` changes with every page refresh. Xpath will not work either as the element changes its position in the DOM with every refresh. There are no constant identifying attributes of the element's parents either.

The only constant is the **length** of the `id` attribute of this specific element, and so I have concluded that this is the only way to grab the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution in pure xpath.

```
//element[string-length(@id)=8]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with an [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector to find all elements on the page that have an `id` attribute (with any value) and then use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (and [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)) to filter them according to their `id`'s length:

```js
console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id]'))
  .filter(element => element.id.length === 3));
  
console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id]'))
  .filter(element => element.id.length === 6));
```

```html
<div></div>
<div id="123"></div>
<div id="456"></div>
<div id="123456"></div>
<div id="987654"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Javascript: How to loop through ALL DOM elements on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256339/javascript-how-to-loop-through-all-dom-elements-on-a-page#4256372) to loop through all elements and then set your own criteria (for the id length) during that loop

Answer (score 0):

You can do first get all the dom elements by using `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` and then use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the required dom element

```js
const domElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
const required = [...domElements].find(element => element.id.length === 8);
```