# Javascript how to change cell colour on timing event?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am currently learning JavaScript and I want to get a cell to blink yellow on a time based event, it seems the JavaScript fails every time I get to:

```
document.all.blinkyellow.bgColor = "yellow";
```

At the moment when my timer reaches 5 it just stops I am guessing it's failing on the above line of code as when I remove it, the timer continues infinitely.

The full JavaScript is below with the relevant html. I would like to know how to properly edit the cell bg colour over time without using a JavaScript library if possible.

This purely so I can learn JavaScript as a whole rather then using a library and not being able to understand the library when I need to make modification or plugin.

**Javascript:**

```
var count=0;
var time;
var timer_is_on=0;
setTimeout(doIt, 3000);

function timedCount()
{
    if(count == 6){    

    document.all.blinkyellow.bgColor = "yellow";

    }
document.getElementById('txt').value=count;

count=count+1;
time=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);

}

function doTimer()
{
if (!timer_is_on)
  {
  timer_is_on=1;
  timedCount();
  }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table> 
 <tbody> 
  <tr> 
   <td>Col 1</td> 
   <td>Col 2</td> 
   <td>Col 3</td>
   <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
   <td class="blinkyellow">Col 1</td> 
   <td>Col 2</td> 
   <td>Col 3</td>
   <td>Col 3</td>   
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
   <td>Col 1</td> 
   <td>Col 2</td> 
   <td>Col 3</td>
   <td>Col 3</td>   
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td>Col 1</td> 
   <td>Col 2</td> 
   <td>Col 3</td>
   <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr> 
 </tbody> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How come your looking for and element with the id of "txt"? Also you're calling doIt in your  setTimeout(doIt, 3000) you may want to change that to setTimeout("timedCount();", 3000);

Also document.all is IE only (Very Important)!

```
var count=0;
var time;
var timer_is_on=0;
setTimeout("timedCount();", 3000);

function timedCount()
{
    if(count == 6){    

    document.getElementById('blinkyellow').style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

    }

count=count+1;
time=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);

}

function doTimer()
{
if (!timer_is_on)
  {
  timer_is_on=1;
  timedCount();
  }

}
```

remember to change the class on the td to an id like this

```
<td id="blinkyellow">Col 1</td>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked I have been trying to do it in jsFiddle but that seems to be buggy whe using .getElementByID I just tried it on a html page on my desktop and it seemed to work just fine :). Thank You Very Much for your help...

Comment: doit is supposed to be doTimer() which just makes sure when button is pressed we don't get any unwanted actions.

Answer (score 2):

When you want a given function to be called repeatedly, for example every second, 
you should use the `window.setInterval(code_or_function, milliseconds)` method:

```
var count = 0;
var interval = setInterval(timedCount, 1000);

function timedCount() {
   count++;
   document.getElementById("txt").value = count;
   if (count == 6) {
       document.getElementById("blinkyellow").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
       window.clearInterval(interval);  // Stops the timer
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a set of elements by class, use the `getElementsByClassName` function:

`var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("blinkYellow");`

You can then loop through that set of elements and apply the style to them, using `style.backgroundColor`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

See an example of this working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/eXRfp/).

Comment: Thanks for your support this worked if I could accept two answers I would.

Comment: @Anicho - No problem! Just bear in mind that if you're using `getElementById` with more than element sharing the same `id`, you are likely to have problems. In that situation, you're going to have to use `class`, as I have done here.

Answer (score 1):

The `document.all.foo` syntax gets elements by `id`, not `class`.

So it'll work if you change `<td class="blinkyellow">` to `<td id="blinkyellow">`.

Or better yet, use the [more supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid) `document.getElementById('blinkyellow')` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use jQuery, then it's simply..

```
$(document).ready(
    function() 
    {
        $(this).oneTime(
            3000, 
            function() 
            {
                $('.blinkyellow').css('background-color', 'yellow');
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Be sure to download [Timers](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the jquery answer appreciated being able to see the difference I am learning pure JavaScript before I decide to learn normal jscript.