# document.documentElement vs document.all

Tags: javascript

Can anybody tell me the difference between these two JavaScript commands?
Also what is the compatibility of these two across major browsers? I know `documentElement` is compatible with most browsers.

Thanks

Comment: [Don't use document.all](http://simonwillison.net/2003/Aug/11/documentAll/)

Comment: people are speaking about `document.querySelector()` now days...

Comment: The question that makes more sense is about the difference between document.getElementById and document.all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid since document.documentElement and document.all are completely different beasts

Comment: actually i want to know the working of these two. i think question was asked by me like that it is looking that i want the comparison of these two. sorry about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`document.all` is a proprietary Microsoft extension to the W3C-standard.
It's an old function and should not be used anymore!

rfc [document.all vs. document.getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid)

Comment: To be noted: `document.all` is nice to have the number of DOM elements on a page. Just run in the console: `document.all.length`

Answer (score 7):

`document.documentElement` is a reference to the root element of the document, usually the `<html>` tag.

`document.all` is a collection type, containing an enumeration of all the children tags within the document.  It's IE specific and should be avoided for cross-browser scripts.

`document.documentElement` is DOM Level 2, so should work in pretty much any major browser these days.

Comment: i was working on a web application that i have to make safari compatible. major issue i faced was document.all was used for IE.is there any equivalent to document.all????