# what to use instead of document.all

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have some JavaScript functions that include code like:

```
if (document.all)
{ document.getElementById('subrow').style.display = 'block'; }
else
{ document.getElementById('subrow').style.display = 'table-row'; }
```

IE 11 returns `false` for `document.all` so the above code no longer works, but I need it to work for earlier versions of IE as well as IE 11 and other browsers.

How can I achieve that? Earlier versions of IE do not understand `table-row` so I have to be able to differentiate.

Comment: I'm not - interested in IE7 and later. And IE7 does not understand 'table-row'

Comment: refer :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663023/what-does-document-all-mean

Comment: IE8+ does understand `display:table-row`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't—use feature detection.**

Trying to detect browsers with indirect tests like checking for `document.all` is, as you have discovered, very unreliable. Best practice is to [use feature detection, not browser detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh273397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Instead, if you want to know if `table-row` is supported, you can check for that directly. This makes your code far more portable because it doesn't tie it to particular versions. Here's one way you could do this based on the [Modernizr display test for table layout](http://pastebin.com/Gk9PeVaQ):

```
function isTableRowSupported() {
    try {
        var style = document.createElement("div").style;
        style.display = 'table-row';
        return style.display == 'table-row';
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/2Dxqr/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use and check `"ActiveXObject" in window` instead which will apply to all IE versions.

`document.all` was(!) a quick check to see if it's IE.

so :

```
if ("ActiveXObject" in window)
{ document.getElementById('subrow').style.display = 'block'; }
else
{ document.getElementById('subrow').style.display = 'table-row'; }
```

Comment: That seems to have broken it for Firefox. IE7 and IE11 work - the row becomes visible. But Firefox no longer works.

Comment: My apologies. I had a typo in the table-row line (on my site).

Comment: Are there any benefits/disadvantages to your solution as opposed to using if (/msie/i.test(navigator.userAgent))?

Comment: @MartinSmellworse much(!) faster

Answer (score 0):

Instead of document.all, if you want to do a check for IE then do it like this:

```
if(/msie|trident/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
   document.getElementById('subrow').style.display = 'block';
} else {
   document.getElementById('subrow').style.display = 'table-row';
}
```

Note: Trident is the rendering engine of IE, which is available in all the versions of IE.

Comment: That works for IE7. It doesn't work for IE11 or Firefox.

Comment: My apologies. I had a typo in the table-row line.

Comment: Are there any benefits/disadvantages to your solution as opposed to using if ("ActiveXObject" in window)?

Comment: try searching for ***Trident***, the rendering engine of IE.

Comment: I'm wondering if IE11 will apply 'block' to a table row - or whether it has moved to using 'table-row'.

Comment: Just tested, IE11 will show a row using block or table-row and so will latest version of Firefox.
Firefox never used to show a row using 'block' - what is going on?

Comment: yes, so you should do it then just using css. like: *.trClass{display:block; display:table-row;}* so, if *table-row* is applicable in any browser, that will replace *block*, otherwise, this will be ignored by the browser.