# How did a doctype break my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, doctype

I made a menu, and just now I added

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

to the document, and it ceases to function. However the code is still running, will still print to console on mouseover etc. I tried other doctypes and they break it too, it just stays static.

What is it about a doctype that could cause JavaScript to not work?

JS:

```
var total_width = "960";
var slide_width = "182";
var slide_margin = "10";
var expand_width = "374";
var icon_width = "32";
var icon_margin = "15";
var slide_number = "5";

function slideid(i) {
    var m = document.getElementById("slide"+i);
    var l = document.getElementById("slideimg"+i);
    var k = document.getElementById("slidetext"+i);
    var j = document.getElementById("slidediv"+i);
    return [m, l, k, j]
}

function compat() {
    if (window.opera) {
        for (var i=1;i<6;i++) {
            s = slideid(i);
            s[3].style.position="relative";
            s[3].style.bottom="46px";
        }
    }
    if (document.all && !(window.opera)) {
        for (var i=1;i<6;i++) {
            s = slideid(i);
            s[0].style.height="60px";
            s[1].style.display="none";
            var iecontents = s[2].innerHTML;
            s[0].innerHTML=iecontents;
            s[0].style.fontFamily="'astonishedregular',Impact,serif";
            s[0].style.fontSize="40px";
            s[0].style.color="#fff";
            s[0].style.textDecoration="none";
            s[0].style.padding="10px auto";
        }
    }
}

function expand(x) {
    if (document.all && !(window.opera)) {
        return
    }
    var shrink = new Array();
    for (var i=1;i<6;i++) {
        if (i === x) {
            var expander = i;
        }
        else {
            var d = shrink.length;
            shrink[d] = i;
        }
    }
    for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
        s = slideid(shrink[i]);
        var slide_shrink = ((total_width-(5*slide_margin))-expand_width)/(slide_number-1);
        s[1].style.marginLeft=(slide_shrink-icon_width)/2;
        s[0].style.width=slide_shrink;
        s[2].style.display="none";
        s[3].style.width="0"
    }
    s = slideid(expander);
    s[1].style.marginLeft=icon_margin;
    s[0].style.width=expand_width;
    s[2].style.display="inline-block";
    s[3].style.width=expand_width-icon_width-icon_margin-7;
}

function shrink() {
    if (document.all && !(window.opera)) {
        return
    }
    for (var i=1;i<6;i++) {
        s = slideid(i);
        s[1].style.marginLeft=(slide_width-icon_width)/2;
        s[0].style.width=slide_width;
        s[2].style.display="none";
        s[3].style.width="0";
    }
}
```

And HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="menu.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="compat()">

<div id="Menu" onMouseout="shrink()">
    <a href="#" class="slide" id="slide1" onMouseOver="expand(1)">
        <img id="slideimg1" src="home.png" />
        <div id="slidediv1">
            <h2 id="slidetext1">Home</h2>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="slide" id="slide2" onMouseOver="expand(2)">
        <img id="slideimg2" src="sound.png" />
        <div id="slidediv2">
            <h2 id="slidetext2">Music</h2>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="slide" id="slide3" onMouseOver="expand(3)">
        <img id="slideimg3" src="blog.png" />
        <div id="slidediv3">
            <h2 id="slidetext3">Blog</h2>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="slide" id="slide4" onMouseOver="expand(4)">
        <img id="slideimg4" src="note.png" />
        <div id="slidediv4">
            <h2 id="slidetext4">Bio</h2>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="slide" id="slide5" onMouseOver="expand(5)">
        <img id="slideimg5" src="way.png" />
        <div id="slidediv5">
            <h2 id="slidetext5">Links</h2>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is so... nostalgic. A blast from the past. To the OP: instead of fixing this script, is it possible to choose one of the ten million other menu scripts which were written in XXI century? :)

Comment: @Sergey I know there are many others, I just like making my own things. Think of it like a hobby, and a good path to learning things.

Comment: @LiamBigelow: I just tried to point out that the code does not follow current best practices, even remotely. It looks like it was written in year 1999.

Comment: @Sergey Oh, sorry I misunderstood. I know that, I think this was my second thing ever done in javascript, and learning things often follow very bad practices. I was about to fix it up when I broke it.

Comment: @Sergey Out of curiosity, what are the worst practices you see?

Comment: Ahh, this deserves a separate question, possibly on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Just to name a few: leaking globals, missing semicolons; unnecessary browser detection; `new Array()` syntax, the whole obtrusive onMouseOver thing... As a learning exercise visit http://jslint.com and tweak the script until it passes without errors - currently it stops at line 19 because of too many errors.

Comment: @Sergey Yep I understand. Those are all things I'm fixing. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add `"px"` to `marginLeft` and `width`. Setting CSS style which requires units will not work without unit. And you are missing `<html></html>` tags.

```
function expand(x) {
    if (document.all && !(window.opera)) {
        return
    }
    var shrink = new Array();
    for (var i=1;i<6;i++){
        if (i === x) {
            var expander = i;
        }
        else {
            var d = shrink.length;
            shrink[d] = i;
        }
    }
    for (var i=0;i<4;i++){
        s = slideid(shrink[i]);
        var slide_shrink = ((total_width-(5*slide_margin)) - expand_width) / (slide_number-1);
        s[1].style.marginLeft=(slide_shrink-icon_width)/2 +"px";
        s[0].style.width=slide_shrink +"px";
        s[2].style.display="none";
        s[3].style.width="0"
    }
    s = slideid(expander);
    s[1].style.marginLeft=icon_margin +"px";
    s[0].style.width=expand_width + "px";
    s[2].style.display="inline-block";
    s[3].style.width= (expand_width-icon_width-icon_margin-7) +"px";
}

function shrink() {
    if (document.all && !(window.opera)) {
        return
    }
    for (var i=1;i<6;i++){
        s = slideid(i);
        s[1].style.marginLeft=(slide_width-icon_width)/2 +"px";
        s[0].style.width=slide_width + "px";
        s[2].style.display="none";
        s[3].style.width="0";
    }
}
```

Comment: And this fixed it, slides nicely now. A few things have been knocked out of line, but that's what I get for not starting with a doctype. Thanks.

Comment: The `<html></html>` tags are completely optional in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

`document.all` is a Microsoft thing, not covered by a standard (more in [this other Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2408424/157247)). Remove all use of it and use `document.getElementById` as necessary instead.

My guess is that if you look in the JavaScript console, you'll see errors related to `document.all` not existing, because while whatever browser you're testing on supported it in quirks mode, when you switched it to standards mode (by adding a doctype), it stopped supporting it.

Comment: I see no errors in console from document.all, right now that's just my crude way of checking if they are on IE and not performing the animation if so, I didn't think that would break the rest of the code

Answer (score 1):

Adding the HTML5 DOCTYPE (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) puts browsers into "Standards mode". Without it, the browser will be in "Quirks mode", which is essentially an IE5/legacy compatibility mode. [MDN has more information on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode), and [a list of differences in behaviour in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_Quirks_Mode_Behavior).

The biggest problem with your script is the use of `document.all`, which is a non-standard Microsoft thing. You'll want to use standard DOM stuff like `document.getElementById`.

Comment: I'm not using document.all for getting elements, just a crude method of browser detection, since the sliding does not play well in IE.

Answer (score 0):

include your count script before closing body tag and dont forget to add closing tag of html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="menu.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="compat()">

<div id="Menu" onMouseout="shrink()">
<a href="#" class="slide" id="slide1" onMouseOver="expand(1)">
  <img id="slideimg1" src="home.png" />
<div id="slidediv1">
    <h2 id="slidetext1">Home</h2>
</div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="slide" id="slide2" onMouseOver="expand(2)">
<img id="slideimg2" src="sound.png" />
<div id="slidediv2">
    <h2 id="slidetext2">Music</h2>
</div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="slide" id="slide3" onMouseOver="expand(3)">
<img id="slideimg3" src="blog.png" />
<div id="slidediv3">
    <h2 id="slidetext3">Blog</h2>
</div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="slide" id="slide4" onMouseOver="expand(4)">
<img id="slideimg4" src="note.png" />
<div id="slidediv4">
    <h2 id="slidetext4">Bio</h2>
</div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="slide" id="slide5" onMouseOver="expand(5)">
<img id="slideimg5" src="way.png" />
<div id="slidediv5">
    <h2 id="slidetext5">Links</h2>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```