# document.all to document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I got this problem on a old website. How to transform document.all to document.getElementById ?

Thank you

```
function _contsetValue(item,vl){

var _item=document.all._cnt_item[item];

_item.style.backgroundImage='url(' + skin_image[23].src + ')'
_item.style.color="#000000";
_item.innerHTML= (item+1) + " " + vl;

var _cnt=document.getElementById('_contbase');
if ( (item+1) > _cntxx){
    _cnt.scrollLeft=(65*(item));
    _cntxx+=7;
}
;
```

Comment: What is in `_cnt_item` array?

Comment: From what I can tell from various websites that explain `document.all`, the above use is not even valid.

Comment: I don't know yet Andrew what is inside _cnt_item... but i am searching !

Comment: I have edited my code if it can help a little bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.all vs. document.getElementById](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid)

Answer (score 0):

`document.all[ID]` is the same as `document.getElementById(ID)` if it's that what you want

Comment: Thanks but it does'nt help me a lot :(