# AppleScript clicking a button in safari error

Tags: macos, button, safari, applescript, automator

I am trying to click a simple button in safari when on a web page using applescript. I have the following code:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    repeat 5 times
        do JavaScript "document.all(\"Roll Again\").click()" in document 1
        delay 2
    end repeat
end tell
```

However, when I run this code, I get an error: "missing value". The event log displays the following result:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do JavaScript "document.all(\"Roll Again\").click()" in document 1
        --> missing value
    do JavaScript "document.all(\"Roll Again\").click()" in document 1
        --> missing value
    do JavaScript "document.all(\"Roll Again\").click()" in document 1
        --> missing value
    do JavaScript "document.all(\"Roll Again\").click()" in document 1
        --> missing value
    do JavaScript "document.all(\"Roll Again\").click()" in document 1
        --> missing value
end tell
```

Could someone please tell me why the button is not being pressed and what missing value means? Is there another simpler way to achieve the button press? I can press the button using automator, however I would like to do it using AppleScript.

P.S. document is the current window in safari

Comment: Please include the URL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48074685/javascript-within-applescript-missing-value-for-clicking-button-in-safari may be useful

Answer (score 0):

[document.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid) is specific to IE and doesn't work in Safari. Try using getElementById or querySelectorAll:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell document 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById(\"nav-badges\").click()"
        delay 5
        do JavaScript "document.querySelectorAll(\"#hmenus a\")[0].click()"
    end tell
end tell
```