# Javascript within AppleScript 'missing value' (for clicking button in Safari)

Tags: javascript, html, safari, applescript

I have the following AppleScript with Javascript contained:

```
set buttontext to "Add Option"
set buttonloc to 1

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell window 1
        do JavaScript "var buttonTags = document.getElementsByTagName(\"button\"); 
        var searchText = \"" & buttontext & "\"; 
        var found; 
        for (var i = 0; i < buttonTags.length; i++) 
        {if (buttonTags[i].textContent == searchText) {
        found = buttonTags[i]; break;
        }
        }
        buttonTags[" & buttonloc & "].click();"
    end tell
end tell
```

It compiles fine but upon execution there is no action and I receive a 'missing value' error. It is designed to traverse a web page in Safari and allow a user to specify the button text and rank to be able to click it.

When execute this Javascript directly in Safari's dev console it works, but I need to have it in AppleScript to wrap it into a longer routine.

Advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve this with amending the end of the JS to:

```
buttonTags[" & buttonloc & "].click();" in current tab
```

Comment: Yes, well done for figuring it out.  *Safari* needs to know where to direct its JavaScript commands.  You had it originally directing it at `Window 1`.  Rather than a `tell window 1` block, you could have had a `tell document 1` block, and then omitted the `...in current tab`.  Or, simply, `tell app "Safari" to do JavaScript "..." in front document`.