# Firefox browser not support menu (click to display)

Tags: javascript, html

I created menu (tree) on my site. When user click on that menu, it will shows two more more menus. It worked on all browser except firefox browser. Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

**html code**

```
<li><a href="JavaScript:ok('tree1');">Sport</a></li>
<div id="tree1" style="display:none;">
    <li><a href="national_sport.php">National Sport</a></li>
    <li><a href="international_sport.php">International Sport</a></li>
</div>
```

**javascript code**

```
function ok(id){
    if(document.all(id).style.display == "none") {
        document.all(id).style.display="block";
    }
    else{
        document.all(id).style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [document.all vs. document.getElementById](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid)

Answer (score 4):

`document.all` is an IE4-ism. It is non-standard and replaced about 15 years ago by (the widely supported) `document.getElementById('id_of_element')`.

Comment: There's a question on stackoverflow that talks about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issues.

- As already mentioned, document.all is IE4+ specific code no longer needed
- Please do NOT use the javascript protocol - there are many reasons not to and none in its favour except one: the status will show the user that the link is javascript
- it is recommended to use unobtrusive scripting and attach the event handlers to the links in the script instead of inline.
- your HTML is not valid

So converting a comment I made to code and adding it unobtrusively I get

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kHy2H/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i=0, n=links.length;i<n;i++) {
    if (links[i].id.indexOf("_link") !=-1) {
      links[i].onclick=function() {
        var id=this.id.split("_")[0]; // get the prefix
        var sub = document.getElementById(id);
        sub.style.display=sub.style.display=="block"?"none":"block";
        return false; // stop following the link
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a id="tree1_link" href="#">Sport</a>
    <ul id="tree1" style="display:none">
      <li><a href="national_sport.php">National Sport</a></li>
      <li><a href="international_sport.php">International Sport</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ok(id){
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none" ) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
    } 
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(id).style.display =       document.getElementById(id).style.display =="block"?"none":"block"`

Answer (score 0):

```
function ok(id){     
var div=document.getElementById(id)
div.style.display= (div.style.display=="block")? "none" : "block";
}
```