# Why can I not name a JavaScript function `all`?

Tags: javascript

`all` is not a built-in function or keyword, but why can I not call a function if it is named `all`?

There is no error message in the debug console, and the function works if I rename it to `all2`.

Here is the code: tested in chrome and IE10

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        function all()
        {
            alert(1);
        }
        function all2()
        {
            alert(2);
        }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="all1" onclick="all()">
    <input type="button" value="all2" onclick="all2()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us how you define and call the function?

Comment: I can do it: http://jsfiddle.net/vNgwQ/ You should provide some more context (code, browser, OS, etc).

Comment: Please test my HTML file

Comment: all is not a reserved word according to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: I confirm success of the all2 button and failures of the all1 button with chrome 31.0.1650.63 (Developer Build 31.0.1650.63-0ubuntu0.13.10.1~20131204.1) Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Firefox on Ubuntu 13.10 also exhibits this behavior. Throws NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Illegal value

Comment: After playing with this a bit, successful behavior can be had by changing the onclick handler to `... onclick="window.all();" >`

Comment: Thoughts:  (1) scope problem with implicit eval? (2) saw something I didn't read about Microsoft adding .all() method to parts of the DOM which would be incompatible with other browsers.

Comment: Summary so far:  You can define a `function all()` but calling it in an event handler set in an HTML string requires some attention to detail.  My question is "why?"

Comment: replacing the event handler with "console.log(all);" in firefox all is pointing to document.all, and in chrome to an object with prototype HTMAllCollection

Comment: @adeneo Perhaps take another look at this `all()` question.

Comment: I think this is a good question. I never knew about document.all already existed.

Comment: document.all is a proprietary Microsoft extension to the W3C standard.

Comment: Not the same question but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2408447/1401094) explains it

Comment: @Paul: For whatever reason, `document` seems to be in the scope chain of inline event handlers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should have worked in chrome. However `all` has been a method in IE until IE11.

> [all is no longer supported. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use getElementById. For info, see Compatibility changes.]
>   Returns a reference to the collection of elements contained by the object.
>   via http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434(v=vs.85).aspx

I remember using it long ago, early javascript days something like this..

```
for(i = 0; i < document.all.length; i++){
   document.all(i)   ...
}
```

It is deprecated in IE now and not implemented in most other browsers, although may still be considered a reserved name because of how wide reaching legacy code may be.

Update: I was able to track down another SO question, they answered it nicely.

> document.all is available only on Internet Explorer, webkit and Opera.
>
> On every other browser all is an undefined property of document object
>   (and undefined is considered as a false value)
>
> As historical note: many (really many) years ago document.all was used
>   to tell Internet Explorer from Netscape Navigator so if you meet a
>   script that is checking if (document.all) ... I strongly suggest to
>   find a better script :)

-[Fabrizio Calderan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10350151/704765)

Comment: i believe most browsers implement it for compatibility with ancient and simple IE-specific sites actually; it was very common back in the day.

Comment: agree with @EHLOVader, it works in Chrome - 

Try executing in Chrome dev tools console and it works-

var all = function (a, b) { return a+b;}
all(2,3);
whereas I have no historical context of all on IE.