# What's the difference between document.links and document.anchors?

Tags: javascript, dom

I tried `document.links` and `document.anchors` in the dev console on a page, and there were 162 links but 255 anchors. However, they are all `<a>` elements.

Up until now, I thought that links and anchors were exact synonyms (as long as they both referred to `<a>` tags). What is the difference technically and or semantically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`document.anchors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/anchors) quite simply returns a collection of all anchors in a document that have a value for the `name` attribute. It has been removed from web standards and **should no longer be used**.

[`document.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links) returns a collection of all `<area>` elements and `<a>` elements in a document with a value for the `href` attribute.

So they're similar, but definitely not identical. `document.anchors` would find anchors like `<a name="foo">foo</a>` (while `document.links` wouldn't), and `document.links` would find `<a href="foo.html">foo</a>` and `<area shape="circle" coords="75,75,75" href="foo.html">` (while`document.anchors` wouldn't).

Answer (score 1):

An anchor is a `a` element with a `name` attribute. In the old days, they were used as linkable section identifiers that can be targeted by the [URI fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). Today, we use `id` attributes for those.

A link is an `a` (or `area`) element with a `href` attribute. It links another page or an anchor thereon.

[`document.links`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-links) and [`document.anchors`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#dom-document-anchors) are live HTML collections of the respective elements in that document. They're rarely used today, `getElementById` and `querySelectorAll` (or the various selector libraries) offer better choices. `anchors` is even deprecated similar to the [horrible `document.all`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2408424/1048572).