# Replacement for document.all JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, iteration

Both Visual Studio Code and the [Mozilla Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/all) tell me that `document.all` is deprecated and should not be used in new websites, like mine.

However, `document.all` seemed to serve a very important purpose: getting a list of every node and their children in a document (either for manipulating the current HTML page, or when parsing XML file or string).

I've seen [a lot of advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid/2408436) that suggests `document.getElementById` instead. But that only solves the problem of using `document.all` with indices to fetch one element (which is pretty obviously bad practice.) This in no way offers a solution for simply getting a list of every element and their children in a DOM, *especially for iterating*.

**What is the proper, modern replacement for this method?**

Comment: how about `document.querySelectorAll("*")`?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("*")` returns exact same # of elements as `document.all` on this page.

Comment: Thanks! I had considered this, but I suspected there may be a performance hit?

Comment: Why do you want to iterate all elements of your document? Use an appropriate selector for whatever you're looking.

Comment: @Bergi I'm actually trying to iterate over some complicated XML from my server, which needs to be programmatically rendered to HTML. (It's a custom markup format, not exactly like HTML). I said I already recognized iterating to find just one element would be bad practice.

Comment: @NatRiddle But also iterating to find multiple elements would be weird. Usually you'd parse your XML using nested loops, possibly recursion, starting from the root node.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I was trying to find if there was a built-in function that recursively loops *for me*.

Comment: @NatRiddle The problem with not using a recursive function means that you can't really distinguish the recursive structure though

Comment: @Bergi This may be true. My general idea was to use the `parentNode` property to help with that. Anyway, I'll try to get something working with your `NodeIterator`!

Comment: @NatRiddle There's also a `TreeWalker` you might want to look at. But recursive functions are the more natural approach to processing recursive structures imo. If you ask a new question about the actual data processing you want to do, with an example of your xml, we might be able to suggest a more concrete solution

Comment: @Bergi Ahh that makes sense, thank you! Maybe I will!

Answer (score 5):

A solution for html would be `document.querySelectorAll("*")`

Comment: Thanks, this helps!

Answer (score 1):

> What is the proper, modern replacement for this method, especially for iterating?

A [`NodeIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator).